# Detect heat waves

Tags: code-golf, math, array, decision-problem

## Background

The Royal Netherlands Meteorological Institute [defines a heat wave](https://www.knmi.nl/kennis-en-datacentrum/uitleg/hittegolf)* as a series of **at least** 5 **consecutive** days of ≥25°C weather (“summery weather”), such that **at least** 3 of those days are ≥30°C (“tropical weather”).

The tropical weather doesn't have to be measured consecutively: for example: `30, 25, 30, 26, 27, 28, 32, 30` is a 8-day long heat wave with 4 days of tropical weather.

<sup>*(Well, by Dutch standards.)</sup>

## Challenge

Given a non-empty list of positive integers representing Celsius temperature measurements from successive days, decide whether that list contains a heat wave (as per the above definition).

The shortest answer in bytes wins.

## Test cases

Falsey:

```
[30]
[25, 30, 25, 60, 25]
[29, 29, 29, 47, 30]
[31, 29, 29, 28, 24, 23, 29, 29, 26, 27, 33, 20, 26, 26, 20, 30]
[23, 31, 29, 26, 30, 24, 29, 29, 25, 27, 24, 28, 22, 20, 34, 22, 32, 24, 33]
[23, 24, 25, 20, 24, 34, 28, 32, 22, 20, 24]
[24, 28, 21, 34, 34, 25, 24, 33, 23, 20, 32, 26, 29, 29, 25, 20, 30, 24, 23, 21, 27]
[26, 34, 21, 32, 32, 30, 32, 21, 34, 21, 34, 31, 23, 27, 26, 32]
[29, 24, 22, 27, 22, 25, 29, 26, 24, 24, 20, 25, 20, 20, 24, 20]
[23, 33, 22, 32, 30]
[28, 21, 22, 33, 22, 26, 30, 28, 26, 23, 31, 22, 31, 25, 27, 27, 25, 28]
[27, 23, 42, 23, 22, 28]
[25, 20, 30, 29, 32, 25, 22, 21, 31, 22, 23, 25, 22, 31, 23, 25, 33, 23]
```

Truthy:

```
[30, 29, 30, 29, 41]
[1, 1, 25, 30, 25, 30, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 40, 1, 1]
[31, 34, 34, 20, 34, 28, 28, 23, 27, 31, 33, 34, 29, 24, 33, 32, 21, 34, 30, 21, 29, 22, 31, 23, 26, 32, 29, 32, 24, 27]
[26, 29, 22, 22, 31, 31, 27, 28, 32, 23, 33, 25, 31, 33, 34, 30, 23, 26, 21, 28, 32, 22, 30, 34, 26, 33, 20, 27, 33]
[20, 31, 20, 29, 29, 33, 34, 33, 20]
[25, 26, 34, 34, 41, 28, 32, 30, 34, 23, 26, 33, 30, 22, 30, 33, 24, 20, 27, 23, 30, 23, 34, 20, 23, 20, 33, 20, 28]
[34, 23, 31, 34, 34, 30, 29, 31, 29, 21, 25, 31, 30, 29, 29, 28, 21, 29, 33, 25, 24, 30]
[22, 31, 23, 23, 26, 21, 22, 20, 20, 28, 24, 28, 25, 31, 31, 26, 33, 31, 27, 29, 30, 30]
[26, 29, 25, 30, 32, 28, 26, 26, 33, 20, 21, 32, 28, 28, 20, 34, 34]
[34, 33, 29, 26, 34, 32, 27, 26, 22]
[30, 31, 23, 21, 30, 27, 32, 30, 34, 29, 21, 31, 31, 31, 32, 27, 30, 26, 21, 34, 29, 33, 24, 24, 32, 27, 32]
[25, 33, 33, 25, 24, 27, 34, 31, 29, 31, 27, 23]
```

Comment: Is the temperature guaranteed to be below 100 Celsius?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Well, in the Netherlands, yes :), but I don't want your answer to abuse this fact, so no.

Comment: What do you mean by decide?  Your test cases imply this means output a truthy or falsy value, but there are other ways of performing decision, such as two consistent values; can we use those?

Comment: @HatWizard Yes, that’s okay. “Crash / don’t crash” is also fine, for example.

Comment: Us folks here in California could sure use this! ;)

Comment: Hey @Lynn this was a great challenge and still is :-)

Comment: @RolandSchmitz Thank you! I'm happily surprised by the creative answers that came out of it so late into the challenge's lifetime. 

Comment: Recommended test case: `[25, 30, 25, 60, 25]`. Without this, the second `:` can be dropped from my regex, making it 37 bytes, and it still passes all the test cases. Also, [Martin Ender's Retina answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/163219/17216) fails this test case.

Comment: @Deadcode added!

Answer (score 31):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>88</s> <s>75</s> 73 bytes

- Saved two bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat).

```c
h,e,a;t(int*_){for(h=e=a=0;*_;h+=e>4&a>2)e=*_<25?a=0:++e,a+=*_++>29;e=h;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVdRj9owDH4ev6J30qaWMilN2lLWlXvbL9jb3YQQK@OkjU2se5gQv52lqZ34SI8WWmAnRVcS2/ns2F@cxftvi8V@vxrlo3lauM/rYjjztsufG3eV5dk8Y@lwlq78LJ@G7@ZT7uXZcPaRRw9y5YPvSyVfTvj@lE/SPFulu/2P@fPa9baDXxtpa@neZ1nmfJp//53/deTn0/reSwdvcLFwt4KNHObc4G/nSUDO269O9uAsJa6Rc3dXuGUEHr94FayddwCWT0YOjlLiauCPg62FZYEXgZHiiRyhHILMxXKMpXY5x@B3XH13crQh0l1h2ackJbXVuJJSVtFiVFlUc@WOHKyF1bfg1Vq5I@vxlPqEVeu00owgTCFoJqDJzTy7YmqeAst2CkMRVFoCLUEYOOSEshQfhJKREIvKRhle1oNTl4BlOx@D5aCypAZaDchaCHklIH/iSuZC9doZVj2rQpIrSQ6hwuoPYTCSR8zMsQuyahdY9cQkTDX/L9dHHSwbPCS8kgJpTWMJhAQpjsN/pLQxfCdnONwAvi9YtsNj0OSQxPxMB3p2@DVYtgOUbiagEYFGYEKirEQkPPAbqazvE@sLlnIY/X1al53m582fYnWk08QOCf9fvfqK2k7TglXbvOmrhpk7VA1gWCUjYG1iriPKzGoXbEJoYIGd9YGE@lo6Cv52sGpuS9RGCwLuVt1sINFFL1Gp3WE3hYI0JwK9ikkLOibN4fEA3QSWHRwGuzLyUMBdRMdb9PzUbwWrntZik3eChEaHRZjQqDDimiB3NhIphBlzWHdvGNak3UnfApbNE6G57jQSZBYssIDkGjt4fQXmGHRL2yY7GnjiUrDs7KDsQYuHkw4tIa@siBQlHg0W6CnP/IbsuBSs14kwIn15Yt7NOn8CspYY@hbnPhBbEmEXWLXpLgR5U4egDQ8Ozm9CbK1g2c4wkiNYBOMDBpmYJkkPsCyYySuU1cxCEFiPw@YG5WqwatleiJeVr6RDwxy6MESPp93M9ifBUo7tBvt/)

Comment: `h,e,a;t` - nice touch!

Comment: @ceilingcat Thank you.

Answer (score 20):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
:5_5Ṡ‘ẆP«LƊ€>4Ṁ
```

A monadic link accepting a list of numbers which returns `1` if a heatwave was detected else `0`.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/KNN704c4FjxpmPNzVFnBotc@xrkdNa@xMHu5s@P//f7SxoY6CkSUUWwCxCRAbI4mZAbG5joIxSMwAyjeDsI0NYgE)** or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##fVQ7TgNBDO05xR4gSLPjmf1Q5AQUtCiKqGiiXIAuogCJkioFSPRwgSAqULjH5iLLrOd57KRAijWbsf38e57V7Xp9N44X8SYOu7fDZjt8Plx9v1/@Ph3uP@Zh2G3G/dfPY/qzfx5223Sm32o6Ni/V@bw6bF6vx3GxILecnVUL388qEXKT8DXVeu27JCEJmbsmSZvMpzuH/03@FuSkKjBNRmcYgYgZgu@mEB7uIX@TzzqiAsemEREDTDuYernP5oJaZzMS14CkkTi7NidZOZMtZQzfZtgGUHV2ZRGY2ugCiicUOfl57ThqZJVHVGlrgDhTrGRjWkvaJuk46uVrqEvnO6DLVDxOmUKL7y5DtTD1qMGrynaoh0mESa3o7BZNJPzP3c8sc0q8fPJ1MkZm5I7P/2SymTwLf8vYnTKFBTNhG4KuV2rYWXJgIbEtpIFdr0Q1FBFzcWG31pBVBhiP0@BwgOewhtwkZTRm7VrdD4cwziy0wJJSJwIhGJJ2hsjBFEjISHRkmCkEQcbS6LJXkmEmjcDauZSpS39r0xB38v7UWlFZY1Rkx2J7583udOadiWYmUqXM5/gVLKOMZss7fe1KkbXRdco4CqV4IvMSBpjjYfC@bEMpRHrQnoym1yUrAihyWrzYlpGZkPIOYRdtS1kddCSlL7Rc/gE).

#### How?

The criteria is the existence of a run of more than four values greater than or equal to 25, of which more than two must be greater than or equal to 30.

If we divide through by five the criteria becomes the existence of a run of more than four values greater than or equal to five, of which more than two must be greater than or equal to six.

If we subtract five from these values the criteria becomes the existence of a run of more than four values greater than or equal to zero, of which more than two must be greater than or equal to one.

If we take the sign of these values (getting -1, 0, or 1) the criteria becomes the existence of a run of more than four values not equal to -1, of which more than two must be equal to one.

If we add one to these values (getting 0, 1, or 2) the criteria becomes the existence of a run of more than four values not equal to zero, of which more than two must be equal to two.

The product of a list containing any zeros is zero and the product of a list containing more than two twos (and the rest being ones) is more than four. This means that the criteria on this adjusted list becomes that the minimum of the product and the length is greater than 4.

```
:5_5Ṡ‘ẆP«LƊ€>4Ṁ - Link: list of numbers
:5              - integer divide by five (vectorises)
  _5            - subtract five (vectorises)
    Ṡ           - sign {negatives:-1, zero:0, positives:1} (vectorises)
     ‘          - increment (vectorises)
      Ẇ         - all sublists
          Ɗ€    - last three links as a monad for €ach:
       P        -   product
         L      -   length
        «       -   minimum
            >4  - greater than four? (vectorises) -- 1 if so, else 0
              Ṁ - maximum -- 1 if any are 1, else 0
```

Answer (score 10):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 64 bytes

```c
h;o(*t){for(h=1;*t;++t)h=h&&*t<25?1:h*(*t<30?2:6)%864;return!h;}
```

The function o() returns 1 for a heatwave or 0 else.

Thanks to the magic number 864 and to [Udo Borkowski](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81057) and Mathis for their ideas.

How does if work? Each sequence of numbers is iterated with a reduce operation starting at the reduce value 1. If a number >= 25 is seen the reduce is multiplied by 2. If a number >= 30 is seen the reduce is multiplied by 2 and by 3 = 6. If a number < 25 is seen the reduce starts again at 1. If the reduce is divisible by 864=2*2*2*2*2*3*3*3 then a heatwave is found, and the result of the modulo operation is 0 which results in a reduce value of 0 and in a return value of true.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xVdNj9owEL3zK9KtdpWwtHI8SQgb6N76C3rr9oCAbZBoqNhwqBC/nQZnxp5lcfhIACSLxLGf34zHb8ajL6PZMPu9@TzNRrPleOL03/LxdP41/bZJk7nbzr3V63zhpgM/aefJ42PupYP04aGd92X47D@l7WJIH8SzfIq8@zgKksUkXy6yT2my3kyz3PkznGaut2r9XRRvr@7dYDBwvg9nb5N/TvH4kt15ScvBH42ZuysQHUc4N/itvYKXcz8umHWcuesWjH7@8ko@a28/WdnrONS2A69G3kJ2Lx8befDNYBkXLSgasL6oaN0CZNsn8D0qn2sZavN0XT7WXSomaPCoHKzACTgsgVXfdmGJoEH5DLL8tl1YNLFLTfKpMloBhOitAAFiBJCmX1wjNE/hYzWKPOKXk4EA0RsSQ0MBRjseFczTUGJsvSzqGHUJPlbjI1zALwFVI3CffQswvADDKCrHNH1ea/OpVFWMdTVBosdIBAJsgoWTMH3iEqpah0@lMIE51DdPH/v4WMlj3KvBOEmrWYyeIaWT@E/K1sXn@AyDbeSb4mM1uIsAEmNZnmlAUwbb@FgN4KrTw4khTvSNZxRYyLyE76Roje1YU3yUwWToS7atNH8slnl6uNKkQon@xY0rzQ98qoo3nXGESaWqodCqMYDfeiYrcYFWi1Etwv2LIq33JdDZyVq83YiPPVsSCAEBplhdc5Dehe/JKRK4qCLDahQg4yJWiXZZcViRLa/Ox@ocgYsLdl@gxaBmFj1HCY7hUylrkQk/YB7S3gHjIeVN@gYsdZOeorcplHURR96ND@z0LfhYdSIwWU8TIoGhc@azkBM7lzDf7IaubI@JDptOXIqPNTq4iPAzJFmhFrPLVsjOJu0QndNTrvm26LgUn4NCGLLyPDbXZx1GPvsWGxWHcy@Ih4SwDp@qcAdgV@sAQfDeIeV1he0oPlZjBAsVOgvdHSHpmVpJN1wAhAkvGqsFhhH5cDmsKFCuxqdK7QHeC4CaFBgB0ecDGtztCrU/iY8ybN3a/Ac)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Very nice first answer complete with test case suite! Could you add an explanation so we understand the magic?

Comment: That's a really elegant solution, well done :)

Comment: **59 bytes**: `h;o(*t){for(h=1;*t;h=*t++<25?!!h:h%72)h*=2^*t<30;return!h;}` - this uses some of the same golfs from [my JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/259589/17216), and a couple more.

Answer (score 9):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>73</s> <s>72</s> <s>71</s> <s>69</s> <s>67</s> 66 bytes

```hs
any(\a->sum[1|x<-a,x>29,take 4a<a]>2).scanl(\a t->[0|t>24]>>t:a)[]
```

Thanks to @flawr and @Laikoni for two bytes each and @xnor for a byte!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVXNbtswDL7nKXTYoQWSQhblv6H1i7g@CFmzFnWyoHaBFuiz15MpUmQyYAciifjx4z/zHKbXp3FcDmGcPs2D2Zi@BztszLZ37dawgF0Fn6GQZ9dE8VFAvVVR6ghf3yz9rtJ3Zo6qTFMldqRhijJR4NvqwpG5T9/BJR1ApkNoSR49QRuCOn5PcGYtEgzY1FPQFDiaVldRWRUtJA5XJ9qKqIpkisI0hdJ5Sh4oydXOScUpR1Q58spl9SRWJcvR2IEKC1Ikrjdli8@kznVviJt74uiTe1DT9yZR1QR1lIETla5PS5CSIIWwo1mpPNHvVPtINWw289v7/CzzKEOYPtFfNKU4wV5@/k9WzGqZZzmPgJWpQaH@IAZI18qY6L6iYx5onVZFuFaGVo0Lw9kEzWo1uNzO8jIMdEf06FYNOnAalVrBWnbFkhurlptpES69rKQ4oLxkDyBeMCLWgZpSHheKmAudd4wjTCPEtLovuetc30IVxF7dokIyyitNGem26No5tUeNujml6glnyf25vIi5laXa@EYuX06yULpGJg58Th5AXUVPcDoSLh0JsCoRrkF91ZpWVi4LUYGV5BmbW6Zc8k2izdQlRbWXluS60PYeHh6XcPq8eQy7bno/9sXXx/0ubD@6CJ7D65Px4T4Mnbu9m/bhNEacmXddb7/mLt7orpt/htt@WI7h5RRPwK8/G2POby@n2fwwx3A2B4P/Vv@8pqOxfO8PY/g9Lbv9@fwX)

Equal length:

```hs
any(\a->take 4a<a&&sum a>2).scanl(\a t->[0|t>24]>>sum[1|t>29]:a)[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVVLb9swDL77V@gwFCvQDLIov4rWf8T1QciatqiTBbV7KLDfPk@mSJHJgB0I23x8fNOvYX5/nqb1EKb5yzyawgwD2LEwd4Pr7gwT2I2QDaWwXRvJRwLFqyM1UX3jWfqu0zsjR1GGqRM6wjBElSCQt7lwZO7TO7gkA8hwqFqRR0@qLak65id1Ri2TGrCpp6ApcDStr6KyKlpIGK5JsDVBlckUiWFKJfOUPFCSm52TilOOKHLklcvqiaxKlqOxIxUWpEhcb8oW2STOdW8Jm3vi6Mk9aOi9TVANqTrKwIlI16cjlYpUSkFHs0p5ou9U@wg1FsXy8bm8yjzKEKYn@oumFCfYy@f/aNPZLPMs5xGwMjVI1B/UAZJ1Mia6r@iYB1qnVZNeJ0OrxoXV2QTNGjW43M7qMgx0R/DoVg06cBq1WsFGdsWSG6uWm2FRXXpZS3FAeckeQLxgRCwDNaU8LhQxFzrvGEeYRohhdV9y17m@pSqIvbpFpWSUV5oy0m3RtXNqj1p1cyrVE86S@3N5EXMrK7XxrVy@nGSpZK1MHPicPIC6ip7U6Ui4dCTAqkS4Bs1VazpZuUwEBVaSZ93cMuWSbxJtpi4pir20JNeFtvfw@LSG09f3p7Drl/D@bHx4CDc38@fRhN7d/pj34TRFqVl2/WB/L328zH0fxUO5fXTjfbgdxvUY3k7xBPz8VRhz/ng7LeabOYazORj8W/3DTUdj/bM/TOFlXnf78/kv)

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 79 bytes

```python
lambda T:any(len(s)>4<sum(s+s)for s in bytes(t>29or(t<25)*9for t in T).split())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVVNb9swDD3Xv0JHaSsGWZT8EXT9Fb1lPaRYgwVInSD2gObXZ5b0KLE57EDYFsnHr0f5fF3@nCa67dVP9et23H28/d6pl81uuurj@6Rn8@yf5r8fev4@m/3pomZ1mNTbdXmf9fLsxtNFL08umG9jVC5R@WJ@zOfjYdHG3MqhbtR2S/b1sVFq68ZHxUI2Sj6ntp67YRW/ComzbpV@tY9nFt9dfi/Yq67gdBk/4TBGyBjpLMZw8Pf5nVzWEVW8ZBsQ08N2gK3jc9gzbpvtiH098kbuybe7y8uKfCljuB64HbDa7JuEcVqh86ifUGf0c6LvqDPpHOJybz3Eino5H9lfqr0qfUfN6Rz60v8B@DwbhyfPosf7AKwetg51OKGTfRphE2DTVvzkF0QsfOcZvEawSMhKwvzMQVZ7pEf26/N/Em2iZyVzIYCtpEmC4SQbgm6sJJFDTZGZ0LKYDnZjJa0kC9uzT/LrBXF5kOFrHike8FNcQXTiOjqxhL1YFos4Viw445IgUQCGF4QdBKm9qJGQE@tIkJSJgpy512XJOEeQh3HlbMrsucet6Im9u5DaWlNZaq5Jzkb2z4lFGsTFE8RcuE6e0d3FWOYZxNIP9QIsdbZCN1Teka/1E4nL0cMeF4XDRUFW1MJ96O/mM9aFKwIssrV@ti1zEzHLxYTFlH1Nel/nUnqzLm9jNs1D/Ld8xn/LslHny2Fa9F5/GtM85A9z@wc)

Answer (score 7):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```apl
1∊8≤4↓⍉×\25 30⍸↑,⍨\⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVNLalxBDNy/U/QBMtAt9fvdxZvBYYJhwAavfIGJHRiTEEIukEWOkL1v0hcZt6qk51kEmkc/fapLJWn/cNx9ftof77/sbo/7x8e720t7/XV3307fy9Cevx4upT1/W9rLn9pOP9v55e33jYxJczv/a6cfn9r5701PuPTQy2HQPBwGWRNPnRMMWtwgS5KaRON3StJD@m/GfbILITR50tQNSGLGaBn225EE4dUuKmZUZar5R4BW@Bf4hRYLYX4xpzK2ggaYWOx09V4OBmopMhvAhLxisXaYVMJYQV5BtUeKawKmZhPgsv6Kk4MwXwoJ1GujJqBsBphdmQUolEvwpUQzLovlzeavAkbitq2uFdRHeIqjWOAYcLhDnGFnvWQOvrV0Q0l4U/PH97@n5h5YOA2ue/bu2IFa5lIYV2/JpqshcyI2WhO8qzc/GsMQRlngHP2nnuPHIwYJGAOOGVGSmmIsZ5@qDLDsc@EA6q0aEyeinxpYDqSOZY/RqNFx9IUkqIbPHx@2NhFgE8y1pwwlaslXy1WcnI80yG16bbVKjNoSqzSGWuRK2dBmYky@DD7pi6@rUy1hXLynWkleNXa4IgT7IMIxclasYL6SbPVJ9IM8zU6eAS5ioHLFMKZb8WauLpYXpO8)

uses `⎕io←1`

`25 30⍸x` is 0 if x<25, 1 if 25≤x<30, or 2 otherwise

we compute cumulative products of these starting from (or equivalently: ending at) all possible locations, discard the first 4 products, and detect the presence of products ≥8 (which is 2<sup>3</sup>)

Answer (score 6):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>19</s> 18 bytes

```js
ô<25 d_Ê¨5©3§Zè¨30
ô                  // Partition the input at every item
 <25               // where the value is less than 25.
     d_            // Then, return whether any resulting subarray
       Ê¨5         // is at least five items long
          ©        // and
           3§      // has at least three items
             Zè¨30 // with a value of at least 30.
```

I hope I got all the discussions in the comments correctly.
Shaved off one byte thanks to [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///AWGyNThZT4w12HVpgeWml8aHnU4RWHVhgb/P8fbWSqo2BsDMEgtpEJEJsD@UDa2BDItoTSQDEj41gA)

Comment: Thought this'd work out shorter when I was reading through it but could only manage [18 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=9DwyNSBkX8qoNakzp1roqDMw&input=WzI1LCAzMywgMzMsIDI1LCAyNCwgMjcsIDM0LCAzMSwgMjksIDMxLCAyNywgMjNd).

Comment: @Shaggy I thought so too, but I couldn't find a shorter version either. Thanks a lot for the pointer!

Comment: Looks like we're winning this one at the moment :)

Comment: Do the non-ASCII characters not count as multiple bytes?

Comment: @sudo Those symbols are all single-byte. For example, `漢` would be 3 bytes, but `¨` is one byte. The symbols used above have been picked for the golfing language exactly for the reason that they're all a single byte.

Comment: [17 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=9DwyNSCuyqg1qTOnWuioMzA=&input=WzI1LCAzMywgMzMsIDI1LCAyNCwgMjcsIDM0LCAzMSwgMjksIDMxLCAyNywgMjNdCi14oQ==) with the `-x¡` flag.

Comment: @Shaggy I don't think that's really a win, the flags are longer than the single byte saved. Sure, it counts as a separate lang for scores, but then it isn't a Japt answer anymore.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>63</s> 51 bytes

Returns a boolean.

```javascript
a=>a.some(n=>(n>24?y+=++x&&n>29:x=y=0)>2&x>4,x=y=0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVTbTsMwDH3nK3gamwZTGqc3UMsbX8Ab4qGCjYvGijZA29ePNjlOzJTwYLVJ7OPLsf3e/XS7p@3b59fVpn9eHlfNsWvabrHrP5bTTdNON602t4d5M5/vJ5PhUF/vm0OjZq2e7Ftz6Q7Hp36z69fLxbp/mV483HXr3eHxYnZzJu9X0wdSj7PZ6aWuL89ZSI0SUaIsKOlqEDMIibtikHIwHu8UzoX7j3sdFD1o4TxbUAbMHaC9Gx1qgBn3T9q9ESXArWGOaAwMKxhqvo8Zs8fMGREDGaSHFC1QcRKxEpmQw9BlzEkB4MwBWWHQTLwZlIlQjtFOp1hEbayiRkRMjoEoURaONEkQhWLHWUSdrBKUPZsVPDPTGl9mtsR/FQMuYaiRu04pyqrXMMhhkAXPFiQXUeDsGB2Bz/4O0f32@@s1MUVhWNw3MTC@e1RoPysg0@oQ3urQYbIJrBOeExl7Ab06zEKy09iYASxIKeaBuc7/BmWdw5kNQswPcVKFmPoyNZAKTpXYNeyEUh2YA92IOajErBhRCkK0/Eai3bmXkA1T4geZo4/1FzuRfHrimZdMlE6dLMosZOu3SDRbSa6suRbDWomFmAsuuQLM63@r3DdELlZOFVa2L0cm3qrQxWQSZSIS69zAGDtLx3YWKZEy1648IbgOc@wFwKRCmVjXEy8CiC9MDL8kxiqbQKyv59jTx18)

Answer (score 5):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 121 bytes

```powershell
param($a)$b="";($a|%{if($_-ge25){$b+="$_ "}else{$b;$b=""}})+$b|?{(-split$_).count-ge5-and(-split$_|?{$_-ge30}).count-ge3}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzfCsIgGMVfReQL/NgMme0ixqg3ES2rgW0yF104n91kUF2dP/zO8dPbzuFhncvZ61k/GWgE01PaFbfu4nBjoPjdNi1GMFVPQRGarAu2xG4jU8IKzHqKjAfvhgUU7i/Ta1zKrOV6vP76wmxnUqQ/IlPO@cykqElzrMlXDwI/) or [Verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##fVTbbtswDH3vV7iGh9pIM8ii5AuKbv2PYQiczukyZE6QpNhD6m/3ZIqUmDz0gbAsHh7eddj/64@n3/1uN23eh9fzdj8km8t06I7d3zzrimz9nKZP7vTx5bLd5Nlq@dZrW1yy9eI5zVZJOva7U@9@nxA5jsUiW398v@TL02G3PWer4uvr/n04OzO77IZf4d5hkAzUGCEwTuNd1h3fTj/UT@dx9vdnvx0ekodikSbLb0m6uL/PN4njHafpJQdVPN695Lp9TFhAzYLXUMZr3TgxTkDcVU5qB5/vFP1X/szMThVoKs@ONExhPQXezS40mRt/Bu11AIEOoZY8GoI2BNV87@HMWnoYsKmhoClwNK1uolIiWvAcuva0FVGV3hSFaUqhM5Q8UJKznY4VpxxRpckrl9WQKJEsRyNKC7FMXHHKF69JHSrfEDt3RdOXu1DTufFUNUE15aCjSlaoJYglSBnZ0cwKT/Tvq49UftRUnD7/xWtnQeGBuv5@JjNmtgxDHHqv4rigUGMQA6Rr43zIhqJjnmSZTUW4Nk6rmBOGswma1WJiuYv2Ogx0R/ToVkw4cBqV2L06LokiN0psNdNCnB9LDEZMaiOm2YgEgSJiHYjx5CmhiLnQYbk4Qj85TCv7ErrO9S1FQdTNI1TGjMIuU0ayLbJ2WixQIx4bK3rCWXJ/rp/C0EorVr2JT15IshS6Jk4cmJA8gHgODcHpddA6bENIhGtQ37SmjZsWhKhAxeQZG1omXPJjRAspS4pqE1sS6gLFfw)

PowerShell doesn't have the equivalent of a `.some` or `.every` or the like, so this is rolled by hand.

We take input `$a` as an array of integers. Set helper variable `$b` to the empty string. Then, loop through every integer in `$a`. Inside the loop, if the integer is `-g`reaterthanor`e`qual to `25`, add it to our potential string `$b`, otherwise put `$b` on the pipeline and set it to the empty string.

Once outside the loop, array-concatenate the pipeline results with `$b`, and put those through a `Where-Object` clause `|?{...}`. This pulls out those strings that have an element length of `-ge5` (based on splitting on whitespace) and a count of temps greater than `30` being `-ge3`. Those strings are left on the pipeline, so a truthy value is non-empty (see the "verify all test cases" link for truthy/falsey distinction).

Comment: try to use `$args ` instead `param($a)` and `$a`

Comment: -2 bytes `...{$a=-split$_;$a.count-ge5-and($a|?{$_-ge30}).count-ge3}`

Comment: 109 bytes with arrays. save `$args|%{if($_-ge25){$b+=$_}else{,$b;$b=@()}}-E{,$b}-B{,($b=@())}|?{$_.count-ge5-and($_|?{$_-ge30}).count-ge3}` as `get-heatWave.ps1`. Test script https://regex101.com/r/lXdvIs/2

Comment: 103 bytes `$b=@();$args|%{if($_-ge25){$b+=$_}else{,$b;$b=@()}}-E{,$b}|?{$_.count-ge5-and($_|?{$_-ge30}).count-ge3}`

Comment: What does `-E` do? I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: -E is short vertion of -End shitch. Powershell allows you to use a significant part of the parameter name. It work :)

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
:5_5Ṡṣ-ḤS«LƊ€Ṁ>4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVQ7TgMxEO1zihwgSLbH3g8FLQ0d5SqiokG5AB2iQeIUSNDBAUgLEvdYLrL488Z@2QIpo3U8M29@b3x3ezjcL8t5uAnz8WU@vp7Nn2/XX@9XP8@/jx/z8eHCL99P8Rh/l8syTZOY/W6z3U5u3G1VxCQp92LbvRui@ChCd12UPtqnO4P/XTlX7KirOF3BzziKEQpGvksxHPx9OYsrOpGGl20DYnrYDrB1eg97xbXFTtTXI2/knn27VV6G8pWC4XrgdsCyxTeL4ljSedQvqDP5Oeo76sw6h7jaWw8xVK/mw/2V1qvad9Sc76Gv/R@Ar7Nx@OosepwHYPWwdajDkY77NMImwMY2/OwXKBb@lxnsE1giZCNh@ZYg0R7piTn9/ifJJnk2MlcCmEaaLBhOthHoxkYSHmqOrITmYjrYjY20TBa1V5/s1xNxdZDhNI8cD/g5LhFdtI6OlrCnZTGIY2jBFVeIRAEYngg7EKk91SjISXVCJFWiIGftdV0yzRHkUVyeTZ299thST8zqQbKtprrUWhPPhvvnaJEGengCzUXr1BmtHsY6z0BLP7QHsNZpSTc03olv9YvQ4@hhj4fC4aEQQ7VoH/rVfMa2cFWAJabVr7Z1bhSzPkxYTO5r1vs2l9qbuLyb/R8)

#### How it works

```
:5_5Ṡṣ-ḤS«LƊ€Ṁ>4  Main link. Argument: T (array of temperatures)

:5                Divide each item of T by 5 (integer division).
  _5              Subtract 5 from each quotient.
    Ṡ             Take the signs.
                  This maps (-oo,25) to -1, [25,30) to 0, and [30,+oo) to 1.
     ṣ-           Split at occurrences of -1.
       Ḥ          Double, replacing 1's with 2's.
           Ɗ€     Map the three links to the left over each chunk.
        S             Take the sum.
          L           Take the length.
         «            Take the minimum of the results.
             Ṁ    Take the maximum.
              >4  Test if it's larger than 4.
                  Note that the sum is larger than 4 if and only if there are more
                 than two 2's, which correspond to temperatures in [30,+oo).
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 86 bytes

```python
lambda l:any(2<s.count('2')*(len(s)>14)for s in`[(t>24)+(t>29)for t in l]`.split('0'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVXJbtswEL37K3ST1AYBxaE2I8mxX9CbYyBuGiMGVNmwlIO/3hGHb8ixDz0MKM3yZidPl/nzONrr/vn1Ouz@/fm7y4b1brwU9ml6fD9@jXOR27z8UQwfYzGVL5Ur98dzNmWH8W1TzC/WlT/90TN7XtjZsH17nE7DYbE0eVle97thujxvNmS2D6uN7R8yITKePJeqxLXdQm4hUrxmoXbR9jyD/yZ8A3eRRJQmYDOKINQBgXneg4W1C99kg4xI0Fizhj8HzQ6aVvisLZhV0CKxdIgYUbNlcxeTUbFSwLAtozZAqoIlk6BUSuaQOSFDb2djrZEfSyx8SkUdyKhMJZZUVUoVQq2RK3MhjTXvgC39sDil/i2@O0ZqoWkRv40SXZseGjU0qoTNVrXyg/9Q9wVpu1rN56/5M4xgGrxweleLFQIkc3v@j7yOt5TxjY03aVSY0BbWIcj6NBy6nexXhlgn1ECvT4OahkS0xYKtWjWs0sT6Ngr2BnT2qoabJItGLV0b18PAi1HLLKgUh6eGvVND2qlBdio7QjwiIzWaMiSIV6oc10ri48ERVN2T2G@pbaWqYe6unirlE5c45KM7outm1ep06oqpVT8kR@nNzfUXu1irFe/SNRczrJSsS7NGTjInUleggzYuBcuXAhmVheTf3nWlT0sWCUhkUuaiG7ulPOIKwirqarLUpW7EmoR1PZ0P45zlv/yzsc5X/K58TPy08FOyDgr7wnNLUX8df/OW31mE1b81uX4D)

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 29 bytes

```apl
∨/(5≤≢¨a)∧3≤+/30≤↑a←e⊆⍨25≤e←⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVQxTgMxEOzzCrqAAMXnte98X6CAghJRRCKhiQQtHwgJEggKPoCQyDt4yn0k@OxZe@M7ik3O9u6sd2e888fV@d3TfPVwv@82z0v/s5sd22773W2/fnfzk27zQ351OiPVb64/5t36fdG9rLvXne79Fn7dvX320fvlxH9dXF9dTm9I3U4nYq3bsyM2Ur0dnlOVz7XzZryR2Ku9NT6u31NY1/F7kMv7JLw65gt4jGUjVtjrc2ngmPhNOp4RDXFDjMUdDGIcYjTvF3Gcp4r@xBgG9aCmgFEX91Ti/hQxdFPg18CsIkYwxqvEmUFfCPX3cXqEJ/Qh@GjcgzkwMCX6wPcb44FyTwc8oSfhHH6JL4d8zKXGP3PX4NsVmA1iNOrUIz6yry18LXyrnC/EW5Eb68iZxzwQsMrijv9DgSfyVRZOMBASfAhnbRaIJDLgs7jlxWr4tVnAY0LhOI4N8Y0QMZNmD@8T8iJPyC9ET1xPLR5oM/KAFPIpMQwYn0YEZIFphHidELgRtRPuyGckhMqiQA3MQXp4fOdCKIwvuUv8MgeV6JUqhliVa0wPvqxRcij7q8XjcmJYWcEb180c/jNcE@9WDAaXh2iqvxJnLuuUzLAvRGLAGsRhqOhiqJASNXKfmoLHNj@@ZMAklfvCvolfkXswzPBYZf@Dn8n8pd71Wv0D)

`∨/` are there *any* elements such that

`(5≤≢¨a)` 5 < the tally `≢` of days in each series (`a` has all the possible series of days)

`∧` and

`3≤+/30≤` 3 ≤ the total `+/` number of elements that are ≥ 30 in

`↑a←` the matrix formed by

`e⊆⍨25≤e←⎕` the series of consecutive elements that are ≥ 25

Comment: Your first test is commented unnecessarily - it works.

Comment: @ngn Thanks for spotting that, fixed

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 48 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.some(x=>x>24?++A>4&(B+=x>29)>2:A=B=0,A=B=0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVTJTsMwEL3zFZygUaFyPM4GShAc@AJuiEMEZVNpEAUEX18S@409rWwOk8WeebO8mXntv/vN/cfL@@fpenhYbh/bbd92/WIzvC1nP23302lzMZ9fduZodjVvx98m6/TZZXvVqhP7zLb3w3ozrJaL1fA0O7697leb37vj7PxAnj/ObkndZdn@oW5ODllITRJRojwo6XoUMwqJs3KUajSezhT@S/cd9zoqetDSebagDFg4QHs2OdQAM@6btLsjSoBbwwLRGBjWMNR8HjNmj7kzIgYySA8pWqByL2IlMiGHoauYkxLAuQOywqC5uDMoE6Eck51OsYjaWEWNiJgcA1GiLBxpkiAKxY6ziDpZJSh7Nmt4ZqY13sxshe86BlzBUCN3nVKUVW9gUMAgD54tSCGiwL9jdAI@2B2im4@vz@fEFIVhce/EwPjuUaH9rIBMq0O4a0KHySawTnhOZOwl9JowC8lOY2MGsCCVmAfmutgNyjqHMxuEmB/ipEox9VVqIBWcKrFr2AmlOrAAuhFzUItZMaIUhGj5jkS7cy8hG6bEDzJHH@svdiL59MQzL7kondpblHnI1m@RaLaSXFlzLYa1FguxEFxyBZjX/1a5b4hCrJw6rGxfjlzc1aGLySTKRCTWuYExdpaO7SxSImWuXbVHcBPm2AuASYUysa4nXgQQX5gYfkmMVTaBWF/Pqae3fw)

quite bad one

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 20 bytes

```
Œʒ24›DPsO4›*}29›O2›Z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVQ9TkMxDL5K1REVKbGTl7yFib3MVB1A4gRISB2QOEOP06VDxcIxuMgjcT4nbgcGN6@x/fnvc1x8efVvy8dh@T7@HCn8fp0en9639bz7pLkcWyo/z8thfTmv7h9Wl/N6s@x27PabHc2blQq7KuWS/bikXCQUYXM3FUnFuN45/J/ad0Mtig4yNWQBUYDYAOSuBiA4h/bN1HTMABPDiGgBhhmGpPfVWBF9M2J1DEgXKYvjdJORM5lyw6BUQScA@eYooiDe6ALKZpRX/Ui7jNpEQYiozQwQZ8rUTHpDeTSndRl1yiWUvdsZyDoJwqmdT/jOFSjBkJA7qcJ2ZYZBhIEfyOIUTRT8bx2vjHKDYu0sl8UQGbG7Pv@TalM9wdM@ZDdYIYIZiA1DNw8i2NlJWKWrLWGC3Two2QmhxuogTsnQUkcWr5OQYACXoIbGrEVMZrmS7oFDEGdWVkFZiRLhHQwds6FsMKUxslEdGxYqJZCttrjvj2ZXaaKgdh590tpXb1rhbt4XP6rpyyrV2GHYnpHZkWzekWhmoRXqXOwL1wcYzSbn8ZL18rzR5cEyDiib2bxyAcZYfSIwv5egtaebgcxjnboAiN0oW237oEzA9s5g52wjRRnGIHo/eL//Aw)

**Explanation**

```
Œ                     # push sublists of input
 ʒ          }         # filter, keep the lists where:
           *          # the product of:
     DP               # the product and
       sO4›           # the sum compared using greater-than to 4
  24›                 # for the elements greater than 24
                      # is true
                      # the result is:
                   Z  # the maximum from the remaining lists where
                O     # the sum of 
             29›      # the elements greater than 29
                 2›   # is greater than 2
```

Answer (score 4):

### Batch, 119 bytes

```
@set h=0
@for %%t in (0 %*)do @if %%t lss 25 (set/as=5,t=3)else set/a"t+=!!t*(29-%%t)>>9,s-=!!s,h+=!(s+t+h)
@echo %h%
```

Takes input as command-line arguments and outputs 1 for a heatwave otherwise 0.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/), 67 bytes

```python
f=lambda l:l>l[:4]and(min(l)>24<sorted(l)[~2]-5)|f(l[1:])|f(l[:-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVXLbuMwDDzHX6GjDbSAJMpPdPsjhg9ZpEYDuE6R@tACxf561pKGEptDD4QlkRq@hvL71/Z6Wel2m/8sx7e/p6NahuV5GQc3HddT@XZey6V6tu7p43LdXk77Zvxnp8e6@p7LZTTDFBfDo5mq23y5qk2dV1UWahxJTw@FUqPtHxQLaS/xnEw@t90ubhcSZ80u7W7vzzT2TVwn7F2XcJqIH3AYo44Y4cz7sLjv4pps1BFlvGBbw6eDbQdby@ewZ1wT7YjvOsSN2MPd5i4uLeKliGFb4DbAMvFuEMYxQueQPyFPf8@KuiPPoLPwy7V1EC3y5XhkfSnXKtUdOYdz6FP9O@Bzbyy@3IsW6w5YLWwt8rBCJ@vUw6aGjcn44V4tfGEfezB5ME/ITML4jU52e4RH@uf3N/E2/mYmcyKAzqQJguYEG4KuzySRTQ2emdAymQZ2fSatJAvb851wrxXE5UbWP@MI/oAf/AqiE@fRiCFsxbBo@NFiwBmXBIlqYDhB2E6Q2okcCTGxjgRJmSiImWudhoxjBHkYV/Ym9Z5rbERN9N2DZHJOaag5J9kbWT8rBqkTD08t@sJ5co/uHsbUz1oMfZcfwJSnEbou845czp9IPI4O9ngoLB4K0iIXrkN7158@D1wSYJHO@bNt6pvwmR4mDKasa9C73JdUm314i2ooDv7f8un/LdugisPhPKvlZS0/qyfbDO/X87qV876rikPcVLf/)

Times out on the longer test cases due to exponential growth. Finds contiguous sublists by repeatedly chopping the first or last element. That 3 days are ≥30°C is checked by looking at the third-largest value `sorted(l)[~2]`. The base cases could perhaps be shorter by taking advantage of truthy/falsey or terminating with error.

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 64 bytes

```hs
f l=or$drop 4l>>[sum[1|x<-l,x>29,all(>24)l]>2,f$tail l,f$init l]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVXbittADH33V8xDHlrwwng0vkHXP2L8YHbrbugkMYkXdmG/va6tkUZKCoUI27oc3ZW38fb7ZwjrNIbbp3k2mel7sENm8t61uWECuxOyoRC2azbyG4HiVRvVm/rOs/RdxXdG3kQJporoCMMQZYRA3u7CkbmP7@CiDCDBoWpJHj2pNqTqmB/VGbWIasCmnoKmwNG0eojKqmghYrg6wlYEVURTJIYplMxT8kBJ7nZOKk45osiRVy6rJ7IqWY7GDlRYkCJxvSlbZJM41b0hbO6Joyf3oKb3JkLVpOooAyciXZ@WVEpSKQQdzUrlib5j7XnG0s/mexJDli3X9@VNZlQGMz7RcIOj2MHeP/9Hu85umeY7jYWVSUKinqEOkKyV0dG9Rsc85DrVivRaGWQ1QqzOJmhWq2HmFpf3YaA7gke3aviB06jUWtayP5bcWLXwDIvq0t9KigPKS/IA4gUjYhmoyeURooi50GnvOMI4Vgyr@5K6zvUtVEHsw30qJKO05pSRbouunVO71ag7VKqecJbcn/srmVpZqivQyDVMSRZK1sjEgU/JA6hL6UmdDoeLhwOsSoRrUD@0ppU1TERQYCV51k0tUy75TtG26pKi2EtLUl0gbu86mfB8uR5er5fZ@NB1/e391BdfHz@eQv7RbSZjCN8657@HoXP5dFjGYzBhezmej4sJw3oaj@dt@18vmTHz9XhezMGcxtlMBv@8/uHGe7H@eZnC@Ou2Pr3M818)

Answer (score 4):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 57 bytes

```
{var r=1;it.any{r*=2;if(it>29)r*=3;if(it<25)r=1;r%864<1}}
```

(-1 Byte by replacing the explicit Parameter *v->* with the implicit parameter *it*)

```
{var r=1;it.any{v->r*=2;if(v>29)r*=3;if(v<25)r=1;r%864<1}}
```

(-16 bytes using the any{} operation as seen in the [Ruby Solution by G B](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166729/81015))

```
{it.stream().reduce(1){r,v->if(r*25>r*v)1 else(r*if(v<30)2 else 6)%864}<1}
```

(-1 byte thanks Lynn: replaced r>0&&v<25 with r*25>r*v)

```
{it.stream().reduce(1){r,v->if(r>0&&v<25)1 else(r*if(v<30)2 else 6)%864}<1}
```

This lambda expression takes a List and returns true for a heatwave or false else.

Thanks to the magic number 864 and to [Udo Borkowski](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81057) and Mathis for their ideas.

How does if work? Each sequence of numbers is iterated with an *any{}* operation starting at the reduce value 1. The reduce is multiplied by 2 and multiplied with 3 (2*3=6) if the number is greater or equal 30. If a number < 25 is seen the reduce starts again at 1. If the reduce is divisible by 864=2*2*2*2*2*3*3*3 then a heatwave is found, and the result of the modulo operation is 0 which results in a true return value in the inner lambda called from the *any{}* operation which then stops iterating and returns value of true.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVZta9swEP7eXyHKBvbIhqST39IksH0YDAb90P0Bf2gaM9cpjlsIIb89s@U76ZxRmc0gLEt3zz26N@v3vqur5vJW1mK3FNHP6tCtfjTdJhafN@Lbfl8/lo1Yi8vprWxFu1Z3VfelbI6n9tNa31XbqOo2uoj7Lxi/VjqJB7H2Y56alTqfL6J/tq@NeC6rJirbp8NSfG3b8rh66NqqeeotnW4EPgONbVkfHo8P5fNL/XjoTdc9pftt5GTowXWQ8eK9PV0sBA2TLURIFpSX1Xk/TD@AraX9GDCGNYnf6TgPcujlHXY6yCI24SYjrl0b7GrENOMc9LgHELZh9RPkZlA/R31N6wEMsq9GXSA8g2fGc1u89Iq/ZOeCEUNnAVsp4qsRzw7CVmzPoO8AfTTo6Zl4o9@svEZ@FD@DQzJfEe@5GIKPRzDe6EMrizou7jnyoJzQ@KYcyHCeB/CzUd9o9IuekefxKdDHCeopz8NiJYwTfo@xjx18fDOp1q597Xb/Uq3IAt9Gvc@8J4G@ATl9h4aRVk2FK91luPSVYgdmmpUB3Ct8FfAMtWyosrnXUpQrfPXOVQNhEI7FylgFUwYmU26WA9q0XFjFA50tZV0rm@kkEm1LX@HOFsxUSYK20LeG8XFcwPOx3GkPWGVihtPZKE6uA9FZAllPtnisXe5RzBTzp7zq/sqf3XXB0Nl5/Hk8NOsyOevyCYsz@YNijvURtJf67us6Z@7/Ss5Hiu3lPt/BhH0HwP5YBjGwA@tABwbJ/EB@za5yoPCdxw3EB@l9R7IuNxiP4F8AuxaPndUxPvbO15PORrOX/mLS1U10@93eRZa3fmu7b0V0sO1OVM30ssJvMhMY8eG0Q6X4LBja@W@Tv2xDDZicdNz/MWmn58sf)

Comment: Nice explanation :)

Comment: I think your byte count should reflect the entire function declaration, not just the function's body. As it is right now, it seems to me to be a snippet.

Comment: @jonathan-frech, I changed the function body to a slightly longer lambda expression including the braces which are not optional like they are in Java. Is this fair?

Comment: @RolandSchmitz Looking at other Kotlin submissions and Java lambda function submissions, I guess not including the function declaration byte count is accepted; meaning that your original submission is most likely valid. Sorry for my comment, it just seemed odd to me as I find it looks very snippet-esk, since it is not a valid language construct without the type declaration.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>66</s> 63 bytes

```python
lambda a:reduce(lambda b,c:(b*(6,2)[c<30]%864,1)[b*25>b*c],a,1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVW7TutAEO3zFW6uSCIXuzvrVwTUVLS3MCns4AgkSFAwSHx9sGfP7E4i3VuMbM/jzHv88TO@HA/uvL97Or917/1zl3Wb0/D8tRuW@O7z3WbZr5dl7lbt7pbM9k9d@tyu2n7tivt@vdvm3fR53ndvnz93bTtp5IvWNXkmRGammUs2cV09kZ@IFK@cqJq0Z57BdxnegTtJIkoZsBlFEIqAwLzZg4O1D@/kgoxI0FizgD8PzRqaTvisLZg2aJFYekSMqNmyvIrJqFgpYLiKUUsg2WDJJChWyTwyJ2Q427lYa@THEgefUlEPMipTiSVVlVKFUGvkylxIY81rYEs/HJ5S/wrvNSNV0HSI30WJrk0DjQIaNmGzVaH84DvUfULaLhbj6Wt8CSOYBi88Z1eTFQIkc/n8H806s6WMb2y8SaPChLawDkHWpOHQ7WS/MsQ6oRJ6TRrUNCSiLRZsValhlSYWl1GwN6CzVzXcJFmUaumquB4GXoxaZkGlODwF7L0a0loNslfZEeIRGanRlCFBvFLluFYSHw@OoOqexH5Lba2qhrk6PTblE5c45KM7ouvm1OrU6sQUqh@So/Tm4vzFLhZqxet05mKGVsnqNGvkJXMidQI9tHEUHB8FMioLyb@66kqTliwSkMikzEU3dkt5xAnCKupqstSnbsSahHX9OL0exuzm8Zg9DN2Y/e2@h83NYn88ZePwOWavh4z/KJugt1/O3JVYPR3@ZRSOwKXV@Rc)

-3 bytes thanks to Lynn

How does if work? Each sequence of numbers is iterated with a reduce operation starting at the reduce value 1. If a number >= 25 is seen the reduce is multiplied by 2. If a number >= 30 is seen the reduce is multiplied by 2 and by 3 = 6. If a number < 25 is seen the reduce starts again at 1. If the reduce is divisible by 864=2*2*2*2*2*3*3*3 then a heatwave is found, and the result of the modulo operation is 0 which results in a reduce value of 0. Only when a heat wave was found the reduce can become 0. Once the reduce value is 0 it will be 0 for all future reduces, i.e. also for the end result.

A more readable, but longer version looks like this:

```python
lambda a:reduce((lambda b,c: 1 if b>0 and c<25 else b*(2 if c<30 else 6)%864), a, 1)
```

Removing extra spaces/parenthesis and replacing `x if cond else y` by `(y,x)[cond]` gives

```python
lambda a:reduce(lambda b,c:(b*(6,2)[c<30]%864,1)[b>0and c<25],a,1)
```

Lynn suggested to shorten the condition `b>0and c<25`:

`b>0and c<25` --> `b*25>0 and b*c<b*25` --> `b*25>0 and b*25>b*c` --> `b*25>b*c`

resulting in

```python
lambda a:reduce(lambda b,c:(b*(6,2)[c<30]%864,1)[b*25>b*c],a,1)
```

Comment: You have to include the import statement too :)

Comment: You actually don’t need to import reduce from `functools`, it's a [built-in in Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce)!

Comment: You can check if `b*25>b*c` and save 3 bytes; this might apply to many of the solutions taking this approach in different languages :)

Comment: @Lynn Many thanks. I updated the solution accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

## [Wonder](https://github.com/wonderlang/wonder), 34 bytes

```
(/>@(& <2!> '<29#0)*> '<24#0).cns5
```

Usage example:

```
((/>@(& <2!> '<29#0)*> '<24#0).cns5) [25 33 33 25 24 27 34 31 29 31 27 23]
```

## Explanation

Verbose version:

```
(some x\\(and <2 (fltr <29) x) (every <24) x) . (cns 5)
```

Take overlapping sequences of 5 consecutive items, then check if any of the sequences have all items > 25 and more than 2 items > 30.

Comment: Hey, this is unrelated, but the facebook link on your website is dead.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 21 bytes

```
L5r⁸ṡẎ<25Ẹ$Ðḟ29<S€2<Ẹ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/HtOhR446HOxc@3NVnY2T6cNcOlcMTHu6Yb2RpE/yoaY2RDVDk////0UZmOgpGlkBsqqNgbADERkC2BRCbQbCxMZAGihsZIslZQMSMTUA4FgA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 89 bytes

```ruby
->a{(0..a.size).map{|i|(b=a[i..-1].take_while{|t|t>24}).size>4&&b.count{|t|t>29}>2}.any?}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVTbjtpADH1uviJPe5GWaDKe3B42fesX9A2hKnRBRd0FRECrLfDtNPEczxi26oMVGNvHt2PvDvOPy/L5Mmm744PJsi7rV38Wj9lbtz2eVqeH@XM3XWXZJJ9l@@734sf7r9Xr4njan/atdedHtm7d3d08@7k5rPfQNOfWnrNu/fH1fNke9n16P2nTb91rv7hPlptd2qerdTpNpmRmT8nUNk@pCJlRxlfK46utB3GDkHorB6kG6/HN4H/pfwN30ASU0mMziiAUHoHfxggW3s7/Jut1RILGlgXiOVjWsLTyztaCmXsrEk@HjJE1e5Y3ORmVK3kMWzFqCaTce7IISq50DpUTKhz9bOg16mONRUzpqIMYVankErtKsUPoNWrlV2hDz2tgyzwsvtL/Cr9rRqpgaZG/DRrdmwYWBSzyiM1ehYqD/77vs3SWvmySL9t0Oe1nyWL9kiSBo993h08UjcT03zGVARUFkLn@/k9Gm9FT6B2IYSKVWDA2tiHomkgePW6OKyTXBZewayKRI4nEWjzYq1JkliEX11lwNKBzVEV@kipKtZRVWB@DKEYtu6BSIFcBf6dIXCuiO1UdIR/RkaKukAj5SpfD2kl@TCxB1TMJ85be5qob5uY05bGesOS@Hj0R3TerVqtWJ6hQ85AaZTZX5zFMsVAnoI5nMFSYK10duUZOKidSJ9LBGkfD8tEgo6qQ@qubqTRxCYMAiUysXGzDtFREnCisqu4ma12cRujJP9b58hc)

Comment: I believe it fails because in the second truthy case, the +30 days are not all within five days.

Comment: Very nice. You can shave off a few bytes with an `each_cons` approach - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVLLboMwEDzXX@FTkkqJBV5eOZTe@gW9IVS5CaiRIhMFUJQGvp2a9RqQIvWwshmPZ9czXNvv@1C@DbtUPTahEErUp9/iVSh9f390ulOiUIefr0Ol64128K27CXU@m13TNakM@tXqJg5VqxtC9n0q@74fLm1T8/Uu5R/qXBdrVlZXXvOT5hnLwMu3LJP7LXcF3lgjCv6MysRUYAoWWGQqNuwR8@g7snvSNSeTSmS1UcUphFYBsbGDpNuB3YO0ZwBODZkh9QuImRBTOnzqDbMOTRTbNyCfTmWS85wfK/Zy4WVW56zQR8Ym1z6v7ZNps1V2HaXNO307HOKL9b8aOeNNHM4ju7xFHGAfaU1GVjSbh2FJMo/sn@LwF2fJbCygPZOmiyYgdkxKElluIiA9jyKX1NuF6VveVKQE7rfwZy64GBcdAbvhi1xsIbFimo1@I1wxxOfQhj8 "Ruby – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 23 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
Æ7)║▄░Ä╟═╙hⁿ╧\ßY8÷K▌µ½x
```

[Run and debug it at staxlang.xyz!](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=923729badcb08ec7cdd368fccf5ce15938f64bdde6ab78&i=[30]%0A[29,+29,+29,+30,+30]%0A[31,+29,+29,+28,+24,+23,+29,+29,+26,+27,+33,+20,+26,+26,+20,+30]%0A[23,+31,+29,+26,+30,+24,+29,+29,+25,+27,+24,+28,+22,+20,+34,+22,+32,+24,+33]%0A[23,+24,+25,+20,+24,+34,+28,+32,+22,+20,+24]%0A[24,+28,+21,+34,+34,+25,+24,+33,+23,+20,+32,+26,+29,+29,+25,+20,+30,+24,+23,+21,+27]%0A[26,+34,+21,+32,+32,+30,+32,+21,+34,+21,+34,+31,+23,+27,+26,+32]%0A[29,+24,+22,+27,+22,+25,+29,+26,+24,+24,+20,+25,+20,+20,+24,+20]%0A[23,+33,+22,+32,+30]%0A[28,+21,+22,+33,+22,+26,+30,+28,+26,+23,+31,+22,+31,+25,+27,+27,+25,+28]%0A[27,+23,+32,+23,+22,+28]%0A[25,+20,+30,+29,+32,+25,+22,+21,+31,+22,+23,+25,+22,+31,+23,+25,+33,+23]%0A%0A[30,+29,+30,+29,+30]%0A[1,+1,+25,+30,+25,+30,+25,+25,+25,+25,+25,+25,+25,+25,+30,+1,+1]%0A[31,+34,+34,+20,+34,+28,+28,+23,+27,+31,+33,+34,+29,+24,+33,+32,+21,+34,+30,+21,+29,+22,+31,+23,+26,+32,+29,+32,+24,+27]%0A[26,+29,+22,+22,+31,+31,+27,+28,+32,+23,+33,+25,+31,+33,+34,+30,+23,+26,+21,+28,+32,+22,+30,+34,+26,+33,+20,+27,+33]%0A[20,+31,+20,+29,+29,+33,+34,+33,+20]%0A[25,+26,+34,+34,+31,+28,+32,+30,+34,+23,+26,+33,+30,+22,+30,+33,+24,+20,+27,+23,+30,+23,+34,+20,+23,+20,+33,+20,+28]%0A[34,+23,+31,+34,+34,+30,+29,+31,+29,+21,+25,+31,+30,+29,+29,+28,+21,+29,+33,+25,+24,+30]%0A[22,+31,+23,+23,+26,+21,+22,+20,+20,+28,+24,+28,+25,+31,+31,+26,+33,+31,+27,+29,+30,+30]%0A[26,+29,+25,+30,+32,+28,+26,+26,+33,+20,+21,+32,+28,+28,+20,+34,+34]%0A[34,+33,+29,+26,+34,+32,+27,+26,+22]%0A[30,+31,+23,+21,+30,+27,+32,+30,+34,+29,+21,+31,+31,+31,+32,+27,+30,+26,+21,+34,+29,+33,+24,+24,+32,+27,+32]%0A[25,+33,+33,+25,+24,+27,+34,+31,+29,+31,+27,+23]&m=2) This takes a long time to run, so I disabled auto-run.

#### Unpacked (28 bytes) and explanation

```
:efc%4>nc{24>f=a{29>f%2>|&|&
:e                              Set of all contiguous subarrays
  f                             Filter, using the rest of the program as a predicate:
   c                              Copy subarray on the stack
    %4>                           Five or more elements?
                        |&        AND
       nc                         Copy subarray twice to top
         {   f                    Filter:
          24>                       Greater than 24?
              =                   Equals the original subarray?
                          |&      AND
               a                  Move subarray to top
                {   f             Filter:
                 29>                Greater than 30?
                     %2>          Length greater than two?
                                  Implicit print if all three conditions are met
```

This'll print all subarrays that can be counted as heat waves, which will be falsy if and only if none exist.

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 19 bytes

```
Vo≥3#≥30fo≥5Lġ(±≥25
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/Pyz/UedSY2UQYZAGYpv6HFmocWgjkGVk@v///2hjAx0jSx0YGQsA)

Using filter (`f`) is one byte shorter than using [checking with a logical and (`&`)](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P@zQcrX8R51LjZVBhAGIaepzZKHGoY1AlpHp////o40NdIwsdWBkLAA), also it would be really nice to get rid of the `±` - costing 2 bytes :(

#### Explanation

```
V(≥3#≥30)f(≥5L)ġ(±≥25)  -- example input: [12,25,26,27,28,29,18,24,32]
               ġ(    )  -- group by
                ( ≥25)  -- | greater or equal to 25: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,0,0,8]
                (±   )  -- | sign: [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1]
                        -- : [[12],[25,26,27,28,29,30],[18,24],[32]]
         f(   )         -- filter by
          (  L)         -- | length: [1,6,2,1]
          (≥5 )         -- | greater or equal to 5: [0,2,0,0]
                        -- : [[25,26,27,28,29,30]]
V(      )               -- does any element satisfy
 (  #   )               -- | count occurences where
 (   ≥30)               -- | | elements greater or equal to 30
 (      )               -- | : [1]
 (≥3    )               -- | greater or equal to 3: [0]
                        -- : 0
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>111 93 71 67</s> 66 bytes

```r
!Reduce(function(i,j)"if"(j<25,!!i,(i*(2+4*!j<30))%%864),scan(),1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVQ9j9swDN3vVyQuDpCvLiCJsmwXWTq0U6dr@wMO7gVwhhRo74D796lNPYpMhg4dCH@QfCQfn/T78m7/@PzzdX52x9fz/LL8OrulO7XNcmzc6RD7br9fOrc8uPg@PexPB/Jte38/5tR2f@ans2u70N4dd4cPl5r/1v435NuKdpmfXlzz5dPXb58/Nl1z16z4bnZbFL/EqduJpaHbVQcFdcRxtbQamX95tS1h@@fxncu7oq/OCpQ3B4AEpC8g/G8rEgGQyjvF4iMygBzco2pC8IjgKP8lQZBDCSRJTmgd7XNyvunMm46pYMRBgDPAQklmE6BgfAkUEEbd8qJlH7OyM6KyEJxg3owsHV2RTEqYso@52YGAuoURFWRDEU/ZyID3UcCGEpwiZonWadmaQEKPoKAVOLE31fBdNrGCsVq/P/64EStQ8UwBZVcEtEz@@vkvS57TghF6VYZXObFhaRxD8E2qHrtsLi1at/NlxE2q5ysVSYIkceJgNC377a8b4YIowIXNGSAZJJsTOtiD5FHIq@YrMFl19UABRclUqlVIK3FX4iMjX@hHuha66wGULkVTAmz3U5UgPAdDi7@5sIJOVU98ncouyHIYzSEbzcXUm93IpLInSFPBs94h9UoY9YqsowbjG1V9lAwFROb6TEjAPRLlHiFvxhEuhpslTXoWqwGMvFIgsXV5pqheXDi0llwOSLqcys@muctf)

Shameless port of [Roland](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166556/80010) [Schmitz's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166548/80010) [answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166555/80010). -4 bytes thanks to Roland and -1 thanks to Giuseppe.

TIO links to functional version.

Previous version extracted consecutive days>25 using `rle` and saved a whopping 18 bytes thanks to Giuseppe!

Comment: if you use `F` instead of `T`, you can do `F=F|"if"(cond,(expr),0)` and then return `F` to save 6-ish bytes. You also have an unnecessary pair of parentheses around `(1-z[i]):0` but I think that could just be `1-z[i]:1` anyway to save another couple bytes...

Comment: ^ I was about to submit the above comment when another idea occurred to me, and I managed to find a sub-100 byte solution! It's `function(x,z=rle(x>24)$l){for(i in 1:sum(z|1))F=F|z[i]>4&sum(x[sum(z[1:i])+1-z[i]:1]>29)>2;F}` but be careful pasting from PPCG into TIO because sometimes unprintables creep in...

Comment: This is fantastic! There is probably an even shorter way leveraging Jonathan Allan's math...

Comment: Nice, you could even save some more bytes, if you simplify the inner part from (i*2*(1+(2*(j>29)))) to (i*(2+4*(j>29)))

Comment: @RolandSchmitz very true!

Comment: `*(j>29)` => `*!j<30` will save you a byte by dropping a parenthesis.

Comment: @Giuseppe nice trick!

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (JDK 10)](http://jdk.java.net/), 60 bytes

```java
h->h.stream().reduce(1,(r,v)->r*25>r*v?1:r*(v<30?2:6)%864)<1
```

(-1 byte thanks Lynn: replaced r>0&&v<25 with r*25>r*v)

```java
h->h.stream().reduce(1,(r,v)->r>0&&v<25?1:r*(v<30?2:6)%864)<1
```

The lambda expression returns true for a heatwave or false else.

Thanks to the magic number 864 and to [Udo Borkowski](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81057) and Mathis for their ideas.

How does if work? Each sequence of numbers is iterated with a reduce operation starting at the reduce value 1. If a number >= 25 is seen the reduce is multiplied by 2. If a number >= 30 is seen the reduce is multiplied by 2 and by 3 = 6. If a number < 25 is seen the reduce starts again at 1. If the reduce is divisible by 864=2*2*2*2*2*3*3*3 then a heatwave is found, and the result of the modulo operation is 0 which results in a reduce value of 0 and in a return value of true.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVZbb5swFH6GX2FVmgRdisA2l6Rp@jat0iZN6qQ9THtgidPSERKByVRN/e2ZMceXAF1f9uAA9jnfd@7xU37Mr542v07F7rCvOXoS30HLizL4VDT82h1tb9tqzYt9FXyp2aZY55xdu@6h/VkWa7Qu86ZBn/OiQn9c14FdLbjsIJd3FWcPrF6tUNF8ZDn/lh/ZXbUu2w3b3FXoxj09Xq0eg4bXLN95fiC02zXzoplXz47@1aq@xLH4Od5Gi/rSOy5JeIsXif8uS6i/jE6O4wiDHEk14NvmZcOe7/PdoWQNukHdcbDfeq7QUe8k9Gf2N57PkFo0naHhOYnMOc7EomIRay8Rq9Pr9kL4Tvr3EZeQ0XhJdw54CivuseRex4UBh/bvBPdnhIxxpU4MNlDQyUAHq/2BnuKJenmiMCj4Az5JjGRgZ2jZT3oMnA7wE8CMegy5FF5knVGICwH/Oz08kSeIg5TBYIfKAYUVWnFQ9k3lgZiYjvIEMZHnIKfzlQGfyiWGp8pdCu/ZADPtdSgGP/GEjB3XOcQpBtnI8En92OKG7z5nvuv4r3UIr1v@@GaHADs8aXRupSAEf0l4/vzXoqFUi8bdpSsvNFUrF1SDlCFwNjfVaVeRtEB1lh2VBOTmpnumqlTpKV2pn1odpComPrdH8gKP5Lc6jih/Ems6pBPdGwJfaDpM45OJ6o0BE@JGLV7NSQyvtFGdEatLoCKVDyoHuuuVzYMqVfh27nTNqBxEVqzCwQSNjI962gx9tHNoxxdbnZ1ZkzK28qb8VjmEWh5xJGaa6amUmQmu/Y@ss8zUKaHjuBBiTXcKejDR8GCikdDyUcUpHeRxbjpfL8AkoYmLktX5tbhHkxQmhR1/KUdN/nTs1DTRf/YNz7l4HPfFBu3ERcC753VRPXz/gfL6ofHFvcBx5AWBs4azWsyYiv2WVwZPTiXn/lns74J9y4OD0ORl5V18kH/ciwsh4Tjbfe2hs7mFGjmw0AJAg/M/@p50EhhdoPdKaeo2EnRnXg/vS/aX12z8KkfnWzZqE88m7X@2sDPyxT39BQ)

Answer (score 3):

## [Swift 4](https://developer.apple.com/swift/), 50 bytes

```swift
{$0.reduce(1){$0>0&&$1<25 ?1:$0*($1<30 ?2:6)%864}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVbbbtswDH33V@ghK@whK2RK8iXY2qc@7BuCPASd0wbo0iDxLkCRb88UmpS4YKsUVJBtieQheXTU46/tZrTnl2FUm0W5/LobV9WnOz@pL@r8NtO3h@Hbj8ehrCv/cqdvbmb1Z3Dqvl7M9MfSvxit7mHRVB@6xp5OZ@V/F2f71@N23P4cHn6vv@9fhqN3t1waPVfQzxXPtl7NC/XOb1nPlf8DRzZifm9YjWZJ78ZvMnYaoGnuaBg/Wv/tssfQmscMlt7BP7O9np5xHSYbtG9oX0/zxUebQnWxYk/sDT22EzL0ZCYUWBGBEJFQZETE@2FawywastWUoUki0oSA@ob5cET0lPTgKC5V2wpsAZeJ2DAPXjNUOcILJubJnQPKJ@TVJXtPESUHAj@5l7WosMgd@VHHOmB2aJ@sg2SH7BMQbk3emYlO9J9rw1ygk5QRlRlF5wcZ0VF0yYZarHXxTBibU0300os@A@G8RIGkBy0qw/VurxhCPTFyUBTc38QzGXpjqTe8D3K4aszfnUVLG5kRemBWK/RWsPDthqf1P4QvGbSP9LJtTlMDSXtBGSO@NXy8qbnUbMijjBHHoKHyWuHdUQGYqCAkFKLcZYgLN8kRThuFmKVr@p70ZOPRDLLuomQHkQCqhMxFixyJgnlSjVGIiIGs4nIIaOp4qUwXQxYnqJ5oBYSVu2uFMDohIDZLkpniAXfSootixZaBGywnzBsWOuZJS89JYWaJt3TNYZQu64LRQsK5VhAlA9iju7qmHfPDH@bi@j@X283r4WH9@Fy@7Q/b3VhuypmuqlNVTK9VcX3i/2tQnP8A)

The closure expression returns 0 for a heatwave or >0 else.

Created in collaboration with [Roland Schmitz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81015/roland-schmitz) and Mathis.

How does if work? Each sequence of numbers is iterated with a reduce operation starting at the reduce value 1. If a number >= 25 is seen the reduce is multiplied by 2. If a number >= 30 is seen the reduce is multiplied by 2 and by 3 = 6. If a number < 25 is seen the reduce starts again at 1. If the reduce is divisible by 864=2*2*2*2*2*3*3*3 then a heatwave is found, and the result of the modulo operation is 0 which results in a reduce value of 0. Only when a heat wave was found the reduce can become 0. Once the reduce value is 0 it will be 0 for all future reduces, i.e. also for the end result.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (ES6)], 49 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.reduce((b,c)=>b>0&c<25?1:b*(c<30?2:6)%864,1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVRNU9wwDL3zK/ZSSDpbxracxKHscu2p1x4YDtkQOnQY0gHK398m9pMtduz2oIljS08fT9Kv4X14HV8ef799eZ7vp@PD7jjs9sPly3T/Z5yq6rAd693@sFfn47VpbvTV4XM1XpO6MVdt/cm1dqvr4zg/v85P0@XT/LO6uP0@b75Nw9vmx/A@3V3UX8/k80N1S@qurk8vTb/dsJBaJaNEOikZt4hdhMRdu0i3GK93Cv9tOOe9LooRtA2ePSgDNgHQ360ODcBsOJMJb0QFcG/YIBoLQwdDw/c5Y/aogxExkEV6SNEDtScRK5EJBQzT5Zy0ANYByAuDavFmUSZCOVY7U2IRtfGKBhExORaiRFk40iJBlIqdZxF18kpQjmw6eGamDb7MbIezywF3MDTI3ZQUZdV7GDQw0MmzB2lEFPgPjK7AZx9n6T@DlOYlfAszExtIpQ70Aj69DuGtT00m@8A74VGR4bfQ69M4FJuNjRnAg3RiJJju5mNQ3jmc@SDECBEn1YrB70ozqeBUiXXDTqjUhA3QrRgFJ8bFilIQouU3Eh3P7YRsmJI4yxx9rsXYieQzEs@8aFE6dbIrdco2LpJstpJcWXMj5tWJndgILrkCzOu/tnlsiEZsHZe2diyHFm8udTHZQpmIxEa3MMbaMrm1RUqkzLXrTgju0yhHATCpVCbWjcSLAPI7E/MvifHKNhEb67n29PEv)

The arrow function returns 0 for a heatwave or >0 else.

*(Port of the [Swift](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166655/81057) solution to JavaScript)*

How does if work? Each sequence of numbers is iterated with a reduce operation starting at the reduce value 1. If a number >= 25 is seen the reduce is multiplied by 2. If a number >= 30 is seen the reduce is multiplied by 2 and by 3 = 6. If a number < 25 is seen the reduce starts again at 1. If the reduce is divisible by 864=2*2*2*2*2*3*3*3 then a heatwave is found, and the result of the modulo operation is 0 which results in a reduce value of 0. Only when a heat wave was found the reduce can become 0. Once the reduce value is 0 it will be 0 for all future reduces, i.e. also for the end result.

Comment: Nice! Even one byte less compared to the Swift solution.

Comment: Very cool! I've got it down to [45 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/259589/17216).

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>50</s> 48 bytes

```ruby
->a{b=1;a.any?{|r|1>b=[b*2,1,b*6][5<=>r/5]%864}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVRNj@IwDL33V/SyQhoBm8RJmmoH9odUPdDD3HaFmBlpEPDbmTZ5jg1a7cEqxPbz17NPn9P5/ra7b/aHy7Szvw7bw9/z78v1dLX7aTdML25t19NLHIfwutuffobxR4r@drsPA5lx3bSD69ctC5lF8jNZeXZpFj8Lqbc4SzebL28G/2P5zcizqsLEgp5hGCIUiPy2hHBw9@U3uaIjqnDZNCCih2mCqeP3Ys6otpgRu3okjcSza3zKyqhsqWC4rsBGQNnimoVhrNJ5FE8ocvFz0nHUmFUOUbmtHmJUsZyNai1Jm7jjqDc/Q107n4DOU3H48hQ6/E4FqoOpQw1OVLpDPUwCTKygZ7egIuF/6f44bv8cjpfr17Vp22P7NnyNza05fn68t6vNZrNqFoYKLcs3x5@hkDeZx@//ZLFZPCu7KymM8CgLJpZtCLpeiKMnnQMzxXWZEXa90FgRiM3ZJbt1iso83vCYRg4H@BxWUZ@4jKiWspPtMQhj1LozLAmxAhC8onBSNPeqQEJGrCPFW6YPMuZG163jDAulGFbPpU6d@2tVQ8zTdbJSUV1yVKTHonvn1GYldYWCmglXyfN5vJF1lEHdgCS3sBZplS4J48jX4onUnfQwx9lw5WyQUYVwD7qn0fSyglUARUaKZ9s6MhWSrxQ2Vbc0q72MpPbl39t8/wY)

Thanks to Roland Schmitz and Udo Borkowski for the idea and the magic number 864. And again to Roland for saving 2 bytes.

Comment: This is a great solution, especially the part with the spaceship and the negative array index.

Comment: You could save 2 more bytes by rearranging and combining the expressions of the inner lambda: 
`->a{b=1;a.any?{|r|1>b=[b*2,1,b*6][5<=>r/5]%864}}`

Comment: Thanks for the idea with the *any{}* operation, which gave me -16 Bytes in the [Kotlin solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166556/81015)

Comment: -1 byte: `->a{b=1;a.any?{|r|1>b=[b*3,1,b*2][5<=>r/5]%72}}`

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 60 bytes

```hs
f q|(a,~(_:t))<-span(>24)q=sum[1|x<-a,x>29,take 4a<a]>2||f t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVVLa@NADL77V0yhBxuSZTwav0qa0173F4SwDG29Dc3DjV1oIexPX6@tkWaUHAoRtvX49FZeXf/2st@Pu0N3Og/qpxvcj1@n42n3rNJ0tc6ypHX7/ks9qkRtNqC3iVpsTLNQTKBnQjbkkW3qiexEIHjlRNWkPvM0fZf@nZEnUYApPTrCMEThIZA3uzBkbv07GC8DCHCoWpBHS6o1qRrme3VGzb0asKmloClwNC1votIiWvAYpvKwJUHl3hSJYXIhs5Q8UJKznYkVpxxRZMgrl9USaZEsR6O3VFiIReJ6U7bIJnGoe03Y3BNDT@5BRe@1h6pI1VAGJopkfRpSKUglj@hoVghP9O1rzzMWfnoxJ7FNkuH8MbzGGY2D6Z9oOMFR7KCvn9/RrDNbhvkOY6HjJCFRz1AHSNbE0ZG9Rsc85DLVkvSaOMhihFidTdCsEsPMLS6uw0B3BI9uxfADp1GKtazi/mhyo8XCMyyqx/6WsTggvAQPEL1gRCwDMbk8QhQxFzrsHUfox4phZV9C17m@uSiIvrlPecworDllJNsia2fEbtXiDhWiJ5wl9@f6SoZWFuIK1PEahiRzIavjxIENyQOIS2lJnQ6H8YcDtEiEa1DdtKaJaxiIoEDH5Fk3tEy45DtF2ypLimIbWxLqAn57x1a9X1K3@Jv@fhiybLXsO3dM18Zm74/9x2GTXz5XS7f4XE/Gg3t7Udat3HZtLpdWDePB7Y7T5j@fEqW68@44qHt1cJ2aZHgVBLu9T/HP7O4uz8Z/T@3e/enH5VPX/Qc)

This combines some ideas from previous Haskell answers in a new form along with [exit by error code](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4781/101474) to come out ahead.

#### How?

`(a,~(_:t))<-span(>24)q` puts the prefix of the list which is entirely >24 into `a`, and then tries to match the remainder of the list to the pattern `h:t` (dropping one value `<= 24` and putting the remaining suffix into `t`). This pattern match might fail even on truthy inputs, if the heat wave is at the end of the list, which is where the `~` comes in: it forces Haskell to match the rest of the pattern even if `_:t` can't be matched (an "irrefutable pattern"), in which case `t` is undefined (i.e. set to `_|_`) and will error out if we ever try to use it.

Since Haskell has the usual short circuiting on `||`, we will only try to evaluate `f t` on undefined `t` if there was no heat wave in the list, in which case we exit high. If there was a heat wave, we'll find it and short circuit out, returning `True` and exiting low.

The irrefutable pattern saves one byte compared to `tail`, which will similarly fail if called on an empty list:

#### [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 61 bytes

```hs
f q|(a,b)<-span(>24)q=sum[1|x<-a,x>29,take 4a<a]>2||f(tail b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVVLb6MwEL7zK1ypB5DIyvaYl5TmtNf9BVEO7oMtKklooFJXym9fFuwZe5LDShkB8/jmPXm348db38/dcThfJvHTTvbHr/Pp3L2KNN3usixpbT/@EU8iEfs9yEMi8r1uckEEciXHBhXZul7ILASMVy5ULeorT@J36d8JeREFmNKjOxiCKDyE460uNJob/w7aywACnFMt0KNB1RpVNfG9OqEqrwZkajBoDNyZlndRSRYteAxdedgSoZQ3dUQwiskMJg@Y5GqnY8UxRyfS6JXKapAkS5aikQcsLMQiUb0xW8dGcah7jdjUE41P6kGF77WHqlBVYwY6inh9GlQpUEVFdGdWME/47WtPMxZ@Ml@TOCTJdPma3uOMxsH0T2e4wGHsIG@f/6NVZ7UM8x3GQsZJcoQ9czqAsiaODu@1c0xDzlMtUa@Jg8xGiNTJxJlVbJipxcVtGM4dwju3bPiB0ijZWlZxfyS6kWzhCdapx/6WsTjAvAQPEL24iEgGbHJphDBiKnTYO4rQjxXB8r6ErlN9FSuIvLtPKmYU1hwz4m3htdNst2p2hwrWE8qS@nN7JUMrC3YF6ngNQ5KKyeo4cWBC8gDsUhpUx8Oh/eEAyRKhGlR3rWniGgZCKJAxedINLWMu6U7htvKSOrGJLQl1Ab@9cys@r6nNn7PtZhzsKd1pk30@jV/Hvbp@bzc2/94tdpP9eBPGbu1hp6/XNp1s14vnbD7a7rSs/us5EWK4dKdJPIqjHUQr/Flg7PYxdf9mDw8qm/@@tL39Pc6bl2H4Bw)

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 23 bytes

```
f&glT5&>T]25gePPT30SM.:
```

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=f%26glT5%26%3ET%5D25gePPT30SM.%3A&input=%5B26%2C%2029%2C%2025%2C%2030%2C%2032%2C%2028%2C%2026%2C%2026%2C%2033%2C%2020%2C%2021%2C%2032%2C%2028%2C%2028%2C%2020%2C%2034%2C%2034%5D&debug=0)

```
f&glT5&>T]25gePPT30SM.:
f                  SM.:Q   Get the sorted subsequences of the (implicit) input...
 &qlT5                     ... with at least 5 elements...
      &>T]25               ... all at least 25...
            gePPT30        ... where the third to last is at least 30.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>54</s> 52 bytes

```perl6
{$_>5&.grep(*>29)>2}o{any kv classify $+=25>*,0,|$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVRda1NBEH3Pr1hCKG29yN6Z3fuBNOKD4oNPWh@klBCkEbHakoAQan97vDt7ZncSxIfJ3uzOnDnz@Xi3ve8OP/fubOOuDk@L1TKevfy2vXs8v1zSeLGk54en9a@9@/Hbfb1f73bfN3u3eHFFcXnZ@ObPYvV82K33bv7uzYdPb7/MX83Sv9eb88Xqwm0etrMb6hrHoXHUTidBfD7lLtSTp5N4kn6SZEe3zeyGffqlcbqDiL3cioW@DJMEIOhdl9E43Xn87/I3cBl@oZ2wBUURIvgEeCBYh/wtcSTurGiiGeEvQHOAJum9aCumxq@WAYzBWiy7E07ecOWMQX3JFNgJc4KF5iNAvOGpSDUnXONDpsBUbvFaMjYAW7NJODV7Pb4HQeqhSeBO5cVGNkIjQqOt2GIVjR/8z1m7zW04v/74@fr9v5qywJczOZ9wQJn98fk/STrJUtuxFNLX0ougsUWH8TbWYtuBEL/alDbEDnpjbTwUvavaaiFWvWk@LWs8ZiHegC5eTbOyRtGZIepLu3t48WY4FZVLO0XYBzPmg1kFwUTH4KNvbJpV2wZ8NctlTJSftJKi2pqUemtuW5MNf7JK2hpPGcocj62IzRuZYRrMyoimHhqj1uZonZUqRrMkh7q2SoSteRtqr3HQyJnNSgvQxlolrFUThcbfn1RlrGNXBEjsa@SqW6plPOYlrsNpsymvoVaj5GQa4MNf)

Comment: I'd love to read an explanation of this code!

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge-98](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), 61 bytes

```
]&:46*`#;_$$$v\+1\;
 +1\_;#`+fe;#<\v
^_v#!`4:\_;#`2:<;\
>0>.@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//@PVbMyMdNKULaOV1FRKYvRNoyx5lIAkvHWygnaaanWyjYxZVxx8WXKigkmVmBRIysb6xguOwM7PYf//00VjA1AyEDBCMY0NkYgUxAEAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), <s>38</s> <s>32</s> 30 bytes

```
{+/7<,/4_'*\'|:',\+/x>/:24 29}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVPLbhsxDLz3K/ZQwG3jwhKpfQf9kcRoenEQJEiBIAcHafzrznI41PpQQFhoqeFoOKQefz7fP5/Ph@n9atdfb3fl9@bH7ebftNneXu2Ov3aTlEbGj/Pr9P715nh6mU6nQ/M23/19nL/dHf48PM3H@W1@@b7/@PJ6k@atpj02Mja@St9ETDNjMjRGq/HbNbKglt@EfWebSqQN87olhjxPai3JfhcyQUaxjYoFVWu2QVpQF0AGQMQjRDlLtnN1eIEeSDJ4d3FrCh1qKdKTo0NqNrgtz8sRLKhCoXlByuoSVFtYwO52FKwUyv2@C0eUpVaXIN9iOKFXA7jcQMHXTeuxGZjaG6QI1MkarpWOqKTFYSaXYdsgxR52WWqemYRvyR7LDW7XtH7/u0pagMzR2pDEztmCh3akCI7sVXXbyH1gqroOpyNnwzuWZzZVCDRsH@PhFrfrPcYKJuOOEVLX1cXs9py7hTuBL3FsyKHsYYa7HasrwUg6JaNd6UGNaUCrXIrbwgn16wfaVthzp2c33JIcRaWLp5gpkXMfEqt9tW6JYRzi4bXhnCt2C9H7StPx3fBFDHzi1JwjOLDLWmoVqvHuC1B4OiJ1yCjPq@kvHBw5qFxI1cQqHEBPg1il9kV19cJOCr1jcbo/fwI)

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 49 bytes

```julia
T->reduce((x,y)->y>24?(2+4(y>29))x%864:x>0,1,T)<1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVRbTuQwEPyfU@RnpUQEyXbbiWe1DJfgD/GBWJBmxSKEFmm4wR6B83GRIWlXP5gPpPE4ie3q6upq/3l93N9Ox4eL49X57uX@9@vdfd8fxrfhfPe2S/myT2e5X562w3D4Uaf887ALYxyvhl/x@Pf2uX9@2T/9e3z6@P/@MHb95prC2KXt2Mmc4824fl3/49gtv1Sw6ubvRg58jHFWRBl5Xs8z@rJMuY0UMFcMWsa6c91DWFsRMt7T8iznQ3vm9dTO8PkJ@7aYV4xZIiunihVy3yZEp8aM3yewZO78hngSk1HnhsjxCAjlax7MF/yYt@xPbY1znVx0ZsJRCVHAkZGy413AQJRMTtlkKgAtAC0YgnLk2BKT8Qp2ZquUsG7feXcBM@zKLj/NjSw/zkDWJBJyTmRaiUcSNFFtKkeVfL2jirlFTyWo7vUKTkdCRZpL8MX7VPtEqhBdfcOJq6JpqmzUPYweoYwo4FytuUTrhuZoRvA@916SagTn7Oo4Rqe9@BV9D27oMkaaMRfXF9lVqbhoWR0zmbqaVbUu0tpFt1bNqZTV62S@xZ0hFd06nyVTJzV1qqkhGNovwkQUECWld2Y813YDOp2lxvOJn@ED8gOcKFhtZK/63HFHVeH6jNuDeVfpK6KvXuJz2byo9STtxOAcK3VMxjZJnHJycxbpmwVpsxmG7vgJ)

The popular `reduce` solution from Udo Borkowski. The final `<1` limits the output to true/false. We can remove it for 47 bytes, but the output will then be either `false` or `0` (varying) for, well, false, and a non-zero number for true.

Alternate version (equivalent) based on G B's Ruby implementation (1 byte longer):

```julia
T->(x=1;any(y->(x=y>24?(2+4(y>29))x%864:x>0)<1,T))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVRBbuMwDLznFb4UsFEXkEjJVna32U/0VvSQS4EWbVAULZD8YJ@w79uPZG1qKLI5FIgi2ZKGw@HQz58vT/vp/Hh7vrvZ9cfb@HN/OPUnWZ92lH73dJ36ZbUdhuNVmdKP4y4Mv@J4Nwzn1/1b//b@dPh4Ofz78/dx7PrNPYexo@3Y6Zziw7i@Xf/j2C0/yth183cjBbkmOCuijjSv9wV92eZUBwXMBYOXsZ5czzD2VoSEZ1rWej/UtexTvSP3J5zbYl4xZo3cOBXssHs3ITpXZvI8gaVwlyfE05iCOldEicdAyF/zEL7gJ7z1PNU9yXVy0YWJRGVEAUdBSo53BgNVkpyyZCoALQAtGELjKLE1puBlnExWKWVd38vpDGY4lVx@LTe2/CQD3dNIyJnYtFKPEDRp2hSJqvl6R2VzS7tFUN3rFZyOjIpUl@CN92nrE61CdPUNF66Kpmlj09wj6BHKqALO1S2XaN1QHS0I3ufeS1qN4JxdHMfotFe/ou/BDV0mSDPm7PoiuSplFy01x0ymbsuqWBe12kW3V8ypnJrX2XyLb4ZWdOt8RqYOVXWKqaEYrV@UiSqgSmrvzFiX@gV0OmuN5ws/wwfsBzhxsNro2eZzxx1VhesTvh7Cu2hfMX/1ktxL5sVWT26dGJxjtY5kbEnj5IsvZ9a@WZA2m2Hozv8B)

Explanation for either version:

```julia
function u_explained(temps)
  x = 1
  for y in temps
    if y > 24
      val = 2 + (y > 29 ? 4 : 0) #2 for 25 to 29, 6 for 30 and above
      x = val * x 
      #If we've reached 5 "summery" days (2^5) of which at least 3 are
      # "tropical" (3^3), then x will be a multiple of 2^5*3^3
      # If we've reached there, make x 0. Else, keep as is.
      x = x % 864
    else
      #found non-summery day, reset non-zero values into 1 (true), but keep 0 as 0 (false)
      x = x > 0
    end
  end
  return x == 0
end
```

---

Older solution:

#### 75 bytes

```julia
T->(l=endof(T))>4&&any(prod(1+sign(T[i:j]÷5-5))>7 for i=1:l-4 for j=i+4:l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVRLbtswEN37FFoFEiIDJIeUaAPOKbwLsjCQupChyEY@i9wgR@hNeoDepBdxpeEbcuJFAdOURPLNmzdvePoYh0N3Pe6u@/VDPe5@TM/nY71vmgd/d3eYPuvL6/m5tvdvw8@p3j8O29PTn99hHeYNfXU8v1bDzm7Htefn026499uxub4cLvPBYXofp79fv45tVa8eybSV27SVzN4@tcvX5d@21fxzAatq/t/who8xzoIow/fLeUafl8mn4QzmiEHzWHYuewhrC4LHu5uf5bxJz7zu0hk@32HfBvOC0UvkzClihdS3DtEpMeP3DiyZO78hnsRk1D4hcjwCQvieB/MFP@Yt@11a41w7FZ2ZcFRCFHBkJK94BzAQJZ1S1hUVgGaAZgpC5sixJSbjBez0pVLCOn3n3QHMsMur/HJuVPLjDGRNIiFnR0Ur8YiDJlmbyFElX@2oUNySTzmorvUySkdCRZJL8EX7NPeJVMGq@pobV9miaWaT3cPoFsqIAsrVORdbuiE5mhG0z7WXpBpGOTsqjlZpL35F34MbuoyResxB9YVXVQoqms@O6Yq6OatYuijXzqq1WJxKPnudim9xZ0hFN8pnrqjjkjqxqCEYuV@EiSggSkrv9HiO6QZUOkuN@xs/wwekBziRKbWRvdnnijuqCtd73B7MO0pfEX33Ep/zxYu5npQ70SjHSh1dYeskTri5OYP0zYy0WjVNdf0H)

(*+13 bytes to fix buggy behaviour for test cases 2 and 9*)

Julia port of Jonathan Allan's brilliant [Jelly solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/163221/8774). Probably not optimal, I just found the method used so neat that I had to try it.

Comment: **47 bytes**: `T->reduce((x,y)->y<25?x>0:(2+(y<30))x%72,1,T)<1` - unfortunately only one of the golfs I used [in JavaScript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/259589/17216) and [in C](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/163188/detect-heat-waves/259589#comment572080_166548) can be used in Julia.

Answer (score 2):

## Regex (ECMAScript+`(?^=)`<sup>[RME](https://github.com/Davidebyzero/RegexMathEngine)</sup>), 34 bytes

```
((:x{25,}){5,})(?^1=(:.*x{30}){3})
```

Takes its input in unary, as a concatenation of strings of `x` characters whose lengths represent the numbers, separated and enclosed on both sides by `:` characters. Example: `:xxx:x:xx:` represents `3,1,2`.

[Try it on replit.com](https://replit.com/@Davidebyzero/Detect-heat-waves-with-lookinto) - ECMAScript+`(?^=)` (RegexMathEngine `-xli`)

```
(                # \1 = the following:
    (
        :x{25,}  # Match and consume a list element that's ≥ 25
    ){5,}        # Loop the above at least 5 times, as many times as possible
)
(?^1=            # Lookinto - match against the contents of \1
    (
        :.*      # Skip to any list element (completing the match of any
                 # previously partially-consumed list element), putting it in tail
                 # (can start in the middle of it and this is still fine, because
                 # we only need to assert that it's ≥ 30)
        x{30}    # Assert tail ≥ 30; tail -= 30
                 # No need to consume the rest of tail if it's > 30, because the
                 # ":.*" part will make sure that we finish matching at the end
                 # of this list element before skipping to a subsequent one.
    ){3}         # Loop the above 3 times
)
```

## Regex (ECMAScript or better), 38 bytes

```
(?=(:x{25,}){5,}(.*))(:.*x{30}){3}.*\2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVPBcpswEL3zFSQXJIcQkATGJjSndiaXHNre2h5ogh01hDBAXBqPv93RrlbEh85ohLTaffv27fKn2lXDfa@78XLo9EPdP7@0T/W/Y1@29V//a739PHWMvZWfrhZHdlOy9bQXaXjge7OxaME5W0eLaS9jY5KHaPFTHBdXbzwaX76NvW63jEdDo@9rloWXivNiV57ftruq0Q@@brvXce2fF5uXnm3KpGBN2dfVQ6PbmnF@VravTVNsypjv9YadbXhnAEfGC8/39cZnTdTU7XZ8xGe2LZto6Bo9siAMOKe364TvTZZh7NmOF3Rq@KFuhnpvcHwfkusyDqcyWAeFvt5SZKEvLhBZD3fVHavKruqH@tYQ2P7Qvzg/xZ0M@d@G@lNxgAA@XSAYfKYg6uuurkZW8eJAD5jYeE5n5Qe/KXquxvtH1vMSK78JvlSG5do3Ed/7V3PwAwNx8OcqzOUoY0@sQrvUMjRXmdBV5KFQoZDumoXCOJhrjOcMDhAuQwrJzBVDrH8K/nA1OAKdFRykAKOUEAivKQIqfM3xVViLR7EJPEnrqZAAcgDP7CRX7LJLCBFLD/goDMek0oYkzqiQtkSSxlOgDsgQLAIxbdUKV@yo2iy2cEkVgQ5IFa5oJDVyRLASCdytLEs85B4cZKgEMhFomWtZIeEU7QkhgFvqoPCMgkCURIYZ7J5H8birxEtCzGxd7P7fpWLjmMAMkOYx9QUWagVPEo0rasesKuDaSZjpZfi6oqbbplgH6wNuS9d3q2f6kQIAEQRg3WxISylzo7jEWYoRKqZ5oHCJbUpDOwlmKYdDIJJwIJE1Stdr7IslYHWgqbNJc8@Gz0KR3rb8xFURn/xKCRGjMTbEZpXmGoUbsNz9OKlTyfK0cmFjASGj4afZzunHJJKJM@bUR6k8kmXlNBE0/0LAyBAfy3x5ItSKJpAWRsmYaFsHks5hwg@FwzmXDEZFElEh8h0) - ECMAScript (SpiderMonkey)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVPBcpswEL3zFTQXpIQwIAHGJjSndiaXHNrems6E2thRS7EL2GGG4dtd7WpFfUhmNEJa7b59@3b5VZ7Kbt2qQ3/b7DfVeVuEeVt8qXafhgP72req2QVt@fp8ZvcFWw2jSPyJj3pjwTXnbBVcD6MMtUlOwfWTOD8HXa3WFYv824jzvK3@HlVbMa@tyk2tmsrjwVqf@@qh6at2W2rXUTWHY786tPt11XVB129UM/Fg3zAPI/y6@DieiquH5lTWauMad/cqV1u25Rdh@2MfvLaq1@meGo/n2yLKHddVW5fVQV01u/6FjzqI7Yo66A616pnne5zT213ExzfRTjx/017zqaq7atQ5XHe7b5kqQn8ovJWXq7sdoebq5gazqu6xfGRlcSjbDqpnu@/qB@fv5xw0/Z9aq9/5BOF8uEFo@Axe0FYHLSMreT7RA9LQnsOH4r1KhuBP2a9fWMuLojnW9b33udQVrFwd/6096oOrdZsm95169RM/y9ARS9@seOHrq4zoKjJfxL6Q9pr6Qjvoa4jnFA4QLn0KSfUVQ4x/Av5w1TgCnWM4SAFGKSEQXhMEjPE1w1dhLA7FRvAkjWeMBJADeKYXuUKbXUKIWDjAJ8ZwTCpNSGSNMdKWSFJ7CtQBGYJFIKapOsYVWqomiylcUkWgA1KFKxpJjQwRjEQCdyPLAg@ZAwfpxwKZCLTMtSyRcIL2iBDALbFQeEZBIEoiwxR2x6F43OPIiXzMbFzM/uaKQ@0YwQyQ5iH1BRZqBU8SjUtqx6wq4JpJmOml@LqkppumGAfjA24L23ejZ/I/BQAiCMDa2ZCGUmpHcYGzFCJUSPNA4RLblPhmEvSKLQ6BSMKBRMYoba@xL4aA0YGmziTNHBM@C0V6m/IjW0V48StFRIzGWBObVZprFHbAMvvjJFYlw9PIhY0FhJSGn2Y7ox@TSEbWmFEfZeyQLEuriaD5FwJGhvgY5osLoZY0gbQwSoZE2ziQdBYTfigczrlkMMYkERUi/wE) - ECMAScript 2018 (Node.js)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVNNb9swDL37VwiGD3ahJbIkO/5omhbodtypxwJGNqRABjfJkhTIYHh/PeOX3BwGCIJIkU@Pj9Rhc@yL6/sflRxbNfT7n@teJfMWzOX989PL08MYve2PaXJamvb@oc0GtX0DKxsOx@3urOLXXdyOcJtDSr88ffw4nSG6019ynWeb33i/@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@4AiIExx8iJ0u9Jr6wgRYB5k6frSKOH0SSvTm8vNQhbn5SrkQkzEGYpNKU402DFgVPk4RVGKeLBc1FhFKGX6Z7Uo@ppDMg7OSPjofiSx10MTK/FuLIyN8mPniRqhaJlAWZTkjtDlApAuY@KFoOKeS0elFIinE/QM) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVNtb9tGDP6uX3HRl945qirdye/Qim5wgQBtMNTFvrTFoNhyolSWNencODD82zOSx3PTLYAgHXnkw4cPqfviR/H6fv39qdq2u86Ke7DjahcP5uK5Z2@r@kVfV96WB7xp9zd1tRKruuh78bGoGnFkV28LC58fu2ottnAhl7armltRdLf9l29K2Ltu99CLxWFVtrbaQWIgxPuqLsUmb8oHOsowXu3WZQz3oZr/vt9syq5cfyqLddmJGwr71Sl9JpsbpeZct4/s/OEO8aXs8xtooVh/qJpSKnWRN/u6VtVG9nH5z76oexm@GQwGoVLHX0MdgpT2RYAjINgzAgC8AYQbiPs@7y/zV1@bV/i185Pznf4srC27RnQ5n6DbbYsF@sh7/ni3XPx9db1cXC@vPl/9tVBzkGm5KpoGJKiadm9FLrBr9snlY2/LbVw1CubWWFHlyVxw4xQf3xX9dXmwwFscBVCuLvJEcdoO7lvQy9aNRIA8xXpQ0YlYQzEH0gACawIYQl7UcdUvtq19JNyPhV3dAcMtJHTx1lkynIWXDim@38FKgB2Jd11XPPZxb0GUrazjvq0rK8MItIPEVjavfwsPIcjdloWVV42F3evituj6EgzZKIizO0LhHfvybTYDSZS6hALA77@9yW28qZq1VOKtCD93@3ImRChmInwPgwMDck7/T6rBezoFuBhP8m0uZ4ejHkYndYSXjAdKyVk8OBxNAi5zigdf9ROuwJNJAj2N3JONIzBNyqaeRDqLtPHmKNIQAGZC5xEeMN1EnDICk1Jc/BDj0QQcTcEZHoxGpzGYiLdDAszodkK32nkCzk3xyrjIjAgQB4wcPauV@OoGU/Q4QD4ZpVNR41JS78yItiGSEKlJB2KIHk2YruuMnsRTdVVc44Y7Qh2IKprkZDUmhOAk0vR2sozpMAnwYKJMExNNnnMvUyI8JH/KCBg29FB0JkEwyxDDEb6DgPPpnaVBGlFlF@LeLz5ZAoEp7gBrnvBc8CGt8MqQc8rjOKuKuG4TzvRGdDvlobuhuAAXg2FjP3en5/BnCQQkEIT1u2EcpZFfxTHtUkJQCe8Dpxsa0zBymwBP5nEYxDAOFnJO42dNc3EEnA68da7oJHDpZ6FYb9d@6rtInv1KKRPjNQZiZ5XOPWq/YBP/4wy9So6nk4sGiwgjXn7e7Qn/mEwy9c4Jz9FkAcsy9Zpo3n@tcWWYj2M@fibUlDeQH8oyCdN2ASydx8Qfipbz3DI6M5aIGzH/Ag) - Java
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVRNj9pIEL37V7TYA23wELvbGDBDIuWQHxDlsKtJhDyeHrACbQsbQWY0fz1sfXQDw672spbH011dr@rVq2rKprlbleXpj8qWm/2TEfePdd12H3ZmZY6jddN8DG6PzLE0TVfV9sNTVawsmKpyWdnnerct0Myocl3sxLJ5@CEW4mvv8@Hw81Hv//r1689v6@ywlif5aSHz46saR2/hK3zkaBCGMh8Njq86BpN@Gw2@q1N4i@xFYtAsls0wmV8xq4DFzhTbj0FlO7EtKitD8RoIeJoHONoYK5vwLvmxiOdiDz5aLTtR4w4BK1y03VOeg29lV2Bs9t2c8GVt205Q6XlOsoidgWBzb2uh7HItDuvCIUAJITHsyznsynSbyhpJm7KyEWcI554lPtWzkC@hADuKJ/vfbR@yvCySOR0RYtRWL0aGi0UcIrOusnszv0SApFAqpiX9B@3l7MyqqVtweJfZY605LAEfCQtdK7q6cknLJegCig4RHMJxgeePrbS4QWewDIW093E4fx8ViCPmJhk@LcAk0hyE0LrNpi5lG0EM5gCH@B2KBP6sDd0quYlPgR7AczjESevn/ffnb8JsWvPf2bec/Crz/8z5DwVQF4YQ4O4GsDXb1nSyhVxcMwEi0T/2UWsYAqblCL4Hg7pwxH16ruyT7EeAQisx9x0Qi8X1hOe5pbY8gvQ/5@wOdV9CX4q4KfVSR3zx5rmu9524vxfy@rIsW1PsyrW8yg1thghQH16ZCG5TKD6J3rfd3uRC9EQuel8KaBr8DzHc1V1kUjvT7XcW07@ddByoWcRvOolgqxO3VdNIpZHSfptFChxgG9M6wwXCdeQgGWwJwv5j9MctxFHknOJCKzRqjUA8HVPAlE6ndKrYEjhsgkeaPVMiQBzQM7vKFfvsGiFqEiCflOCUVDMk8caUaGsiCZ6KdCCGaFEUk6tO6Y09Vc7ChWtXEepAVHFLRqfGlCKwRIq@LMuEFtMAFzpKFTFRZDnXMiPCY7InLgK6jX0oWpMgiNLEMMNvEDg8fdMkSCLKzC78/dc3jcExwRlwmseuL/iSVnikyThz7TirinF5Es70MjqduaZzU9iBfdBt4vvOeo4vKTAgBcGwfjY0U8r8KE5olmIKFbt5cHBNbRpHPAnwpj6OC6JdHEzERu17TX1hAqyDmzpOOg0YfhbK6c3lJ76K@OoqJY6YG2MgdlbpXKPyAzb1F2fsVWKeLBc1FiNkbvjdbE/dxXQkE2@cuj7qNHCyzLwmys2/Ujgyjg8zn1wJNXMT6F5C6djRZgcnnY@JF4qG81wyGlMnkStE/y6fN8WqPd1t6DdvST95fwM) - Boost
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVPbbtswDH33Vwh9sZxqhiTKl3gw9iHpHro1RV14TmB7QNug356JF7l5GCAIEkUeHh5S5/f15TTBdfhzPs2rWt4XMx@zWfVqvru7u@ofve7eLr4yn8UlbrrcFYXuyt3bBWw0wWe5e/DX6Hpw3Tf387v66G32fJrVqIYJ4cplfRqmLlNqeFYfnTrPw7Tqgu/jcdJjoR6nJzUeYnjf5w9T3qmxHw8W8W7dUuxxeur1ss761@k06vlYLsfH@feLno3Ku1zd416@noZJ52/5DiOGQiGlASmN5XIeh1XnJi8Kdi62Qzm@/l1W3RTI7yvbWGBd7go283vDKzQmXsHJ1bfGB@MhXWvjo0O8WjrXeMBwMBJSxyuFsH@F/niNOJ6cAx7AoxEAA/G1IsBAry29erZkEuvwCdgzEAHigJ71TS6bsgOG@CZDPoHCKSlwiEvGQLSBSEZPTzoQQ7R4wuSqAy2bqHIWLhykItSBqOKVjKJGSwgskaedZWno0GZ4ABM8MfFk2WrZE@GK7E4Q0K1KUHQmQTAKiGGNe5ZJPO3BZc5QZnbh/b8r2OjocAZEcyt9wUVa4ROQcS/t2FRFXJ6EjV5Nr3tpOjeFHdgH3ZrUd9az@kqBgASCsGk2gCnVaRQbmiVLUFbmQcKB2lQZnoS4QsIREBAcTMRGSL2mvjAB1kGmjpO2GYdvQoneXL5LVdibr@SEmIxxJLaptNXo04C16eNUSSXmyXJRYxGhluGX2W7lYwpJl4yt9BFCJrLskyZe5t97HBnhw8ybG6H2MoGyKAqs0GYHkS5h4oei4dxKRmMQiaQQ@Ac) - Python
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVPJbtswEL3rKxhfJLmKwE2bDcEIkPbYQ5FbEhguqqQqFEewZMSB4/66w1mo@lCApsnhzJs3b0a7/c/3807U4kfz3Bz6dNu8idubu5t012x@LUVby6V4@912jejq52YcAiHaJ9HdX6vHup49bGdL99DdyzS91o9L0Wwh6Em0VxDY78fB22qFD1dd2rz04/vKAQnR79rtKKIoXITii@jSoe/aMQqTME5fNv3xY/iYHWbzIR1f122kZHxK/7y2W3CPnT/@1X/FLhYrEd7t9s1CiFAsRPht0w3uEi45Q@eyORoB/Nbrr99v1@tztKqjxeGos@QUH90WpfM4jhbp/HA00pnMKZ0/6PPZyEBXCS1bJO5qFF91mWibaOOveaKdg7tKPOdwgHCTcEjurhhC/hn4w9XhaHS2cDAajMZAILxmCGjxtcRXTZaAYxU8GfK0SAA5gGd@kUv67AZCdBEAH4vhmNRQiPJGi7QNknSeGnVAhmDRiElVW1zSU6UsVLjhikAHpApXNLIaJSKQRBp3kqXAQxnAwSRWIxONlqmWCglnaFeMAG6Zh8IzCgJRBhnmsAcBx@NuVaASzEwutP93WekcFcwAay65L7BQK3gyaKy4HZOqgEuTMNHL8bXiplNTyIF8wK3wfSc9s38pABBBANbPhiFKuR/FAmdJIpTkeeBwg23KEpoEt6zHYRDDOJCIjMb3GvtCBEgHnjpKWgYUPgnFelP5ylchLz4lxcR4jB2xSaWpRu0HrPQfTuZVIp4kFzYWEHIefp7tkj9MJqm8seQ@GhuwLJXXRPP8aw0jw3yIeXEhVMUTyAujjGTa5MDSeUz4oHA4p5LBaFkiLsR8Ag) - Ruby
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVZtT9tIEP6eX7FNpcYOhvNLEkKCqVrIqUgUqjToeqWVFZwNserYlu0cFI6/ftzM7KzjEO7uwyGz7M7OyzPPzO4SZtnuTRg@vZ7JeZRI8el4PHKD44uTUXB5fjoJfjs9mXwQ/cbrKAnj1UyKwyzMpbu3OGqEi2kuguzqu/DFuPn@9vbHtbf6/efPL5NF73ZhPBlvfWNw9@B2rUfzAQZjr22axmCvfffg2SDyHvfa39wn87ll0xLtzA@yHWdYC1uUeZTcYNy1LEpBKqfLoy29o0aUlCKDaRnIPE9zI0yTohSEub2URTG9kaZ4KMrZYBCChjg8FCzGKcllMouHIpflKk@EM3zc8onrMJ1JS1ynaSxSfz6NC3RLYdjdldvtfR82BPxEc2EQfcGNZB8BaxnKj6H4vzz@8G7cb5u8aYkiupfp3KiA/6IlNX3TNCkK/hipeKuSCNNVKQaiStTE9JpkJgjBQDSfJU/GzSZYNb8lTbPiYx6vioXKpCKloVhZTqPEgMRpM7uCIsQyMTJz1/nu20OxAh3PDUqgyFYOyKGqlYiSbFUOhWIGeRDtXOr1clqGi2A2LadQt2o@FBg1l8UqLi2Vx5B79/Pp1xFJ5vNCwibkD1huysWGQjv9Q4YlWHE60MM6/jKLYmkws58/TcZmZrHp19H4IpiMxh9Pz99NRidaPPoyGZ2fjE7Enyz4eHk2OT07PR9Z4g2B478MyTbX/fAqh3IynfXeopH1ahz4W7QEsJ6WMpjn6TLIpmUp88TIoWfOL8/O2EHdBg5CKe9KYFPP/Jf22a2x5QUyYM04Wkalod1YYtcxhzWlmczK/1TKZbjKiyhNXlSksPM0F3TU7rGVqHHg@MRwWxmqq6PEUj1kDnULanbvTQFyPI5G61vSgtD3vjOkLbLYw2NkmL5vmwIjR8lKDtceICj0DoZVF0ex3qtQZWkBChuRtW0ibwOwt0QCHE/LNOKgYQCdD8dlB41N2Ma6Tq8LI8EFKoNkRxjJoe6Uek5o8ywYnSgwMxBm24TKxXEaGgVcKIwBNnHcEQ78JonJM@eZf3J0BZo7O3ittwatzf1HIeGG@/foSxW8Fvl/xtxiAHlRJmSw@8xgKZfQWkYBsVTOZGCJ1l0LuYYmULAY4KYxsAtbqk7wIs6MlgVWKCXkugLC9@t32GCQUFmugfofQ6Xu4/W4ncSzVNd52GttdbFtHkw60/VbCapLzWXTt74QYM6HqEY0wlZeD23x5g1HeOXzBTYeX4yD84uP7ybHH8xNPmp3kr5vy3wla76xJTZs1g8PvibK6si38VWZgOlACHpcfsXXEv6@@MJs@VGvxPr85RLOP6N4/KdbLiC1NR/bt6dSqNZm/R1Sm3BBV/8FqFzg1Xvy7IZ7YKmvs2/B0nN46fYtt2O5nl72LBcUYGnTvIcTNPcsNunBkkyUfhf1cQl@XFLu4MRzUeh5aIi7XXLYod0@7bpK0mBbB7c8pdkhAIQBNXu1WLaO7qGJu99APB0yp6CeMnG0sEOwPQIJmi7xQAhR4pJPlXWHPltDVVFU4h5nhDwQVFySkNnokwdFkUujomWfJv0GTjyr4xISlyRVLgcEuEtyhz2gWle7ojkRglYeIezh2GiwPY0dp@FYFFmpqPHFr2ODooM9wJzbXBf8iCvc8kh4wOWoWEW/qhMqeD3aPeCiq6IoBaWDavu67orP7joEOiQn6Fb3hqcg9XQr7lMv2eTK5n5gc4/K1LVUJ8DX0X7Yicd@MJASerrWVBcFQPHAXaeC9hvKvCKK@VbpOzoLu3aUHAbGbQzAKpaqHF3dYH19cLqaJYVT0UWFRQ89bn7u7T4fTAbpaGGf6@h1GkzLgebE5f53XWwZxqOQ79eIOuAO5I@sPJthKwWmTvvEA0XNWaWMwg5TxIl4f4XzeHpTPO3GdF3t9v8G) - PCRE
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVNNj5swEL3zKyzkCsiSCGxDCFHUlSr11ltv21UVbb0bKkoiwirRUn576vkwu4dKlrHHM2/evBlOx4vtzwfbtjfZ7x56@2Kvj3Xd2Ut8H93iz7u4vo6qSKdkdFu8WiRJXK8W11FnzqSn1eKHukX3afjl@OfUtPZXmGzl2y7bPh97u386xLIVTSdk051eh2RsnmP5loyXvhns8nA8D5NzzrcC7O2qtd3LcEhGud/Jdnk@tc0QpuFWyOsurMO7OJZ78Vd8EmN0jRYPTTc8yp9Tsvx9bDr3nty5bSvescWyO7pC2qazIpQx5OhX3/bD08GeY3lNkjH63r/aWkSTsO3ZOtyve/etoykRsg2n6aazQG1SWmaduqvO@aqqVJlUaX8tU@Uc3DXDcwkHCNcph5TuiiHkX4A/XB2OQmcDB63AqDUEwmuBgAZfK3xVZAk4NocnTZ4GCSAH8Cw/5Mp8dg0hah0AH4PhmFRTSO6NBmlrJOk8FeqADMGiEJOqNrgyT5WyUOGaKwIdkCpc0chqVIhAEincSZY1HqoADjo1CpkotMy1bJBwgfacEcCt8FB4RkEgSiPDEvYg4HjcTR7kKWYmF9r/u0zmHHOYAdY8477AQq3gSaNxw@2YVQVcmoSZXomvG246NYUcyAfc1r7vpGfxngIAEQRg/WxoolT6UVzjLGUIlfE8cLjGNhUpTYJbxuMwiGYcSERG7XuNfSECpANPHSWtAgqfhWK9qfzcV5F9@JVyJsZj7IjNKs01Kj9glf9xCq8S8SS5sLGAUPLw82xX/GMyydwbK@6jNgHLsvGaKJ5/pWBkmA8xX38QasMTyAujdMa0yYGl85jwQ@FwziWD0bBEXIj@Bw) - .NET
[Try it on replit.com](https://replit.com/@Davidebyzero/Detect-heat-waves) - ECMAScript (RegexMathEngine)

```
(?=
    (
        :x{25,}  # Match and consume a list element that's ≥ 25
    ){5,}        # Loop the above at least 5 times, as many times as possible
    (.*)         # \2 = the remainder of the string
)
(
    :.*          # Skip to any list element (completing the match of any
                 # previously partially-consumed list element), putting it in tail
                 # (can start in the middle of it and this is still fine, because
                 # we only need to assert that it's ≥ 30)
    x{30}        # Assert tail ≥ 30; tail -= 30
                 # No need to consume the rest of tail if it's > 30, because the
                 # ":.*" part will make sure that we finish matching at the end
                 # of this list element before skipping to a subsequent one.
){3}             # Loop the above 3 times
.*\2             # Assert that at some subsequent position, \2 can be matched,
                 # demonstrating that the 3 loop iterations above only matched
                 # list elements that occurred within the same range of the string
                 # as that matched by the 5 loop iterations at the beginning.
```

While golfing this, I found a bug in Ruby's regex engine triggered by 39 byte version: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVNLT9tAEL77Vyy52KbG2pdfiawIifbYQ8UNUBRUQ12ZYNmOCArpX093HutyqLTZ7Ly/@WY87B/fz4OoxY/muTn06a55EzfXt9fp0Gx/rkRby5V4@9V2jejq52YaAyHaJ9HdXamHul7c7xYrZ@juZJpe6YeVaHYQ9CTaCwjs99PodbVCw0WXNi/99L52iYToh3Y3iSgKl6H4Irp07Lt2isIkjNOXbX/8GD8Wh8XlmE6vmzZSMj6lv1/bHbjHzh//6j9iiMVahLfDvlkKEYqlCL9tu9EJ4YordK6agxHAb7P5@v1mszlH6zo6HHWWnJbx0d1RehnH7rp/PByNPMVHc3KCPp@NDHSV0LFF4kSjWNRlom2ijRfzRDsHJ0p85/CAcJNwSO5EDCH/DPxBdHk0Olt4GA1KYyAQrBkmtGgt0apJE3CsApMhT4sAEAN45p9qSV/dQIguAsBjMRyLGgpRXmkRtkGQzlMjD4gQNBpzUtcWj/RQqQo1brgj4AGhgohKZqPEDESRxptoKfBRBvAwidWIRKNm7qVCwBnqFWcAt8ynwjcSAlEGEeZwBwHH421VoBKsTC50//dY6RwV7ABzLnkucJArMBlUVjyOmVXIS5sww8vRWvHQaSjkQD7gVvi5E5/ZvxKQEJNAWr8bhiDlfhUL3CWJqSTvA4cbHFOW0Ca4Y30eTmI4DxQipfGzxrkQAOKBt46KlgGFz0Qx39S@8l3IT5@SYmC8xg7YzNLco/YLVvoPJ/MsEU6iCwcLGXJeft7tkj9MBqm8suQ5GhswLZXnRPP@aw0rw3gIefGJqIo3kA9GGcmwyYGp8znhg8LlnFsGpWWKuBHzFw) / [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVRLbtswEN10pVMw3khKZYE_yZINwQiQdtlFkV0SGA4qpyoUx5BlxIHj5iDdZNEeKj1HD1DOh2oWBWiKM5zPmzdD__jZ7W4eX17_dKISn-vber9J1_WDOD-7OEu7evllJppKzsTD16atRVvd1v02EKJZifZyrK6ranS1Hs3cRXsp03Ssr2eiXoPTSjQn4LjZ9VuvqxRenLRpfbfpH-cukBCbrln3IorCaSjeizbdbtqmj8IkjNO75ebwtH0a7Uen27S_XzSRkvEx_XbfrME8dvb4qb6LLhZzEV50u3oqRCimIvy4bLdOCGecoXXZHIwAfovFh0_ni8WvXb8aF69hNK-i_UFnyXEaH9wepadx7Larm_3ByGN8MEcnaDJ_4c_vd89GBrpMaNlJ4kSjWNRFom2ijRfzRDsDJ0o853AAd5OwS-5EdCH7DOxBdHE0Gls4GA1KY8ARbjMMaPG2wFtNmoB9FVwZsrQIADGAZf4ml_TZDbjoSQB4LLpjUkMuyistwjYI0llq5AERgkZjTKra4pIeKmWhwg1XBDwgVBBRyWwUGIEo0rgTLRM8FAEcTGI1ItGoGWopEXCGesURwCzzofCMhICXQYQ57EHA_rhbFagEM5MJ7f9dVjpDBTPAnEvuCyzkCq4MKktux8AqxKVJGODleFty06kpZEA2YDbxfSc-s38pICAGgbB-NgxByv0oTnCWJIaSPA_sbrBNWUKT4Jb1cTiI4TiQiJTG9xr7QgCIB546SloE5D4QxXxT-cpXId88JcXAeIwdsIGloUbtB6zwDyfzLBFOogsbCxFyHn6e7YIfJoNUXllwH40NmJbSc6J5_rWGkWE8hHzyhqiSJ5AXehnJsMmAqfMx4UHhcA4lg9IyRVyIoT-ivw) - it gives false negatives on all of the truthy test cases, while working fine in all the other regex engines.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 44 bytes

```
a=>a.reduce((b,c)=>c<25?!!b:b*(2^c<30)%72,1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVRNb9swDL3vV6SHIfaQFpIo@aNtuutOu@6QdoDjusOGIi7arn8/s@VHiQ2k9UDIlsjHj0fyT/fWvfTPv59ezw/j/XB82B677U138Tzc/@2Hothv@nJ7018b9/XsbH@5/1KYn/01qfJzbTa6PPbj4WV8HC4ex1/Fevd9XH0butfVj@5tuLs9rMurT1LhodiRuivL00vjNitSm9V8Vv5MKbXTA2RWTiKRjkqmmcROQuKumqSejOc7hf9q@U6HNikG0AphWgHoFkB/Nzs0ALPLN5nljSgD7g0dorEwbGBo@D5lzB71YkQMZJEeUvRA1UnESmRCC4apU04qAOsFyAuDavFmUSZCOWY7k2MRtfGKBhExORaiRFk40ixBFIudZhF18kpQDmw28MxMG5zMbI3vJgVcw9Agd5NTlFVvYeBgoKNnD@JEFPhfGJ2B3yGvbw@7DycuzsxyZuYmNJGKXegFnHodwlsbG032gnfC4yJTqKDXxpHINhwbM4AHqcVYMOXufVDeOZz5IMQYESdVieGvc3Op4FSJlcNOKNeIDuhWjEMjRsaKUhCi5TcSXc8thWyYkjDPHH2qzdiJ5DMQz7xoUTp1si91zDYsk2S2klxZcyNmthF70QkuuQLM6/82emgIJzZPEzd3KIcWb03sYrKZMhGJrW5hjNVlUquLlEiZa1efENzGcQ4CYFKxTKwbiBcBpPcmdoAkxivbSGyo59zTx38)

This is based on [Udo Borkowski's JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166659/17216) which is **49 bytes**. The extra golfs are:

1. Change `(c<30?2:6)` to `(c<30?2:3)`, because multiplying by both \$2\$ and \$3\$ simultaneously is redundant and doesn't keep track of any more information than if we just multiply by two different primes. Thus instead of `864`, we can use `108` as our magic number, as the sum of the multiplicities of \$2\$ and \$3\$ is now equal to the previous multiplicity of \$2\$.
2. Change `(c<30?2:3)` to `(c<30?3:2)`, thus getting `72` as our magic number instead of `108`, saving 1 byte.
3. Change `(c<30?3:2)` to `(2^c<30)`, taking advantage of bitwise `^` having a lower operator precedence than the `<` comparison operator. This saves another 2 bytes.
4. Move `b>0` from the ternary condition, to its truthy argument. This saves another 2 bytes.

This is still "inverted logic", returning falsey for a "Contains a Heat Wave" and truthy for "No Heat Wave". But as a result of change #3, the return value for "Contains a Heat Wave" is sometimes `0` and sometimes `false`. This can be cleaned up by `!`, taking it to **45 bytes**: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVRNb9swDL3vVySHIvaQFZIo@WNruutOu@6QdoDjusWGIh7arn8/s@VHiQ2k9UDIlsjHj0fyd/faPfdPv/68fDqOd8Ppfnfqdtfr7vJpuPvbD0Vx2Pbl7rq/Mu7ren34fPhYmJ/9FanyojZbXZ768fg8Pg6Xj@NDsdl/H1ffhu5l9aN7HW5vjpvyywepcF/sSd2W5fmlcdsVqe1qPit/ppTa6QEyKyeRSEcl00xiJyFxV01ST8bzncJ/tXynQ5sUA2iFMK0AdAugv5sdGoDZ5ZvM8kaUAfeGDtFYGDYwNHyfMmaPejEiBrJIDyl6oOosYiUyoQXD1CknFYD1AuSFQbV4sygToRyzncmxiNp4RYOImBwLUaIsHGmWIIrFTrOIOnklKAc2G3hmpg1OZrbGd5MCrmFokLvJKcqqtzBwMNDRswdxIgr8L4zOwG@QNzfH/bsTF2dmOTNzE5pIxS70Ak69DuGtjY0me8E74XGRKVTQa@NIZBuOjRnAg9RiLJhy9zYo7xzOfBBijIiTqsTw17m5VHCqxMphJ5RrRAd0K8ahESNjRSkI0fIbia7nlkI2TEmYZ44@1WbsRPIZiGdetCidOtuXOmYblkkyW0murLkRM9uIvegEl1wB5vV/Gz00hBObp4mbO5RDi7cmdjHZTJmIxFa3MMbqMqnVRUqkzLWrzwhu4zgHATCpWCbWDcSLANJ7EztAEuOVbSQ21HPu6dM/)

The original explanation (edited to reflect the changes):

Each sequence of numbers is iterated with a reduce operation starting at the reduce value \$1\$. If a number \$≥ 25\$ is seen, the reduce is multiplied by \$3\$. If a number \$≥ 30\$ is seen, the reduce is multiplied by \$2\$. If a number \$< 25\$ is seen the reduce starts again at \$1\$. If the reduce is divisible by \$72=2×2×2×3×3\$ then a heatwave is found, and the result of the modulo operation is \$0\$ which results in a reduce value of \$0\$. Only when a heat wave was found the reduce can become \$0\$. Once the reduce value is \$0\$ it will be \$0\$ for all future reduces, i.e. also for the end result.

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 59 bytes

```
lambda a:reduce(lambda b,c:[b*(2+(c<30))%72,b>0][c<25],a,1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVU7b9swEN79K7QUsVsNJI96GUnnTlkzyBpkR0YCpHLgKAXy613p@B15MZAMB8r3@O59fv2Ynk6juxzvdpeX/u/@sc/67Xl4fD8Ma/ze54dtu/@5dr/Wh1sym82PyuX736ZrD7eu6PI@t5vLsX95@7hrWzJdvmpdkWdk8mx5S36Z28xfIF8tGguXbOK6eiY/EyleOdOivfAMfpfhG95mSUQp4dkrhCIgMG/x4GDtwze5ICMSNNYs4M9Ds4amEz5rC6YNWiSWHhEjarYsr2IyKlYKGK5i1BJINlgyCYpVMo/MCRkudi7WGvmxxMGnVNSDjMpUYklVpVQh1Bq5MhfSWPMa2NIPh1fqX@G7ZqQqaHqH@F2U6No0yLqAhk3YbFUoP/gd6t51q9V0fp@ewlgCCq@3i6PZBuHJsMr7HXnDZlaGN7bdpEFhQlNYhyBr0mjoZrJfGWGdTgm9Jo1pGhHRFgu2qtSoSguLz1GwN6CzVzXaJFmUauWquBwGXkwa5YhKcXQK2KMyXvmI@JR8cDwiIzWYGBGJV6ocl0ri47ERVN2T2HeprVXVMFeHx6Z84gqHfHRHdN2cWpxaHZhC9UNylN5gCoFcpnMQF7xORy5maJWsTrNGXjInUgfQQxsnwfFJIKOykPyrq640acUiAYlMylx0Y7eURxwgLKKuJkt96kasCS/r6/l5nLKb@1P2Z@in7KH/N2x3483qeDpn0/A2Zc9jxn8z26B5XC/cjdjtxq/Nwh34bHf5Dw)

A port of the above. 4 bytes shorter than [Udo Borkowski's Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166701/17216) which is **63 bytes**.

Clean `True`/`False` output is **61 bytes**: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVU7b9swEN79K7QUsVsNJI96GU7mTl07yBpkR0YCpHLgKAHy613p@B15MdAOB8r3@O59fv2cns6ju57u99eX/s/hsc/67WV4fD8Oa/w@5Mdte/i@dj/Wxx2ZzeZb5fLDg@na484VXd7ndrOz11P/8vZ537ZkunzVuiLPyOTZ8pb8MreZv0C@WjQWLtnEdfVMfiZSvHKmRXvhGfwuwze8zZKIUsKzVwhFQGDe4sHB2odvckFGJGisWcCfh2YNTSd81hZMG7RILD0iRtRsWd7EZFSsFDBcxaglkGywZBIUq2QemRMyXOxcrDXyY4mDT6moBxmVqcSSqkqpQqg1cmUupLHmNbClHw6v1L/Cd81IVdD0DvG7KNG1aZB1AQ2bsNmqUH7wO9S961ar6fI@PYWxBBRebxdHsw3Ck2GV93/kDZtZGd7YdpMGhQlNYR2CrEmjoZvJfmWEdTol9Jo0pmlERFss2KpSoyotLL5Gwd6Azl7VaJNkUaqVq@JyGHgxaZQjKsXRKWCPynjlI@JT8sHxiIzUYGJEJF6pclwqiY/HRlB1T2LfpbZWVcPcHB6b8okrHPLRHdF1c2pxanVgCtUPyVF6gykEcpnOQVzwOh25mKFVsjrNGnnJnEgdQA9tnATHJ4GMykLyr2660qQViwQkMilz0Y3dUh5xgLCIupos9akbsSa8rK@X53HK7n6ds59DP2W/@49hux/vVqfzJZuGtyl7HjP@m9kGzdN64W7Ebj/@2yzcga92178)

## [Python 3.8+](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>62</s> 59 bytes

```
lambda a,b=1:[b:=[b*(2+(c<30))%72,b>0][c<25]for c in a][-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVU7b9swEN79K7QUsVsFIHnUw0bcuVPXDrIGybWRAIltOGqB/HpXPH5HXj1kOJC6x3dPni4f0/P5RO3lejtud7fX4W38PRRDOW7tphs32278unTflvsnMqvVl8aV43fTd/snV/XH87XYFy@nYui7R9vfjsPr@8e268j05aJzVVmQKYtw1nwydz3fQL4JGoFLNnNdO5OfiRSvniloB57Bdx3v8DZLEkoNz14hVBGBecGDg7WPd3JRRiRorFnBn4dmC00nfNYWTBu1SCw9IkbUbFnfxWRUrBQxXMOoNZBstGQSFKtkHpkTMgx2LtUa@bHEwadU1IOMylRiyVWlXCHUGrkyF9JU8xbY0g@HU@rf4N4yUhM1vUP8Lkl0bdbIuoKGzdhsVSk/@I517/vFYrr@mZ7jWAIKp7fB0WyD8GRY5fyMvGEzK8Ob2m7yoDChKaxDkK3zaOhmsl8ZYZ1ODb11HtM8IqItFmzVqFGVFlb/R8HegM5e1WiTZFGrJ9ekx2HgxeRRTqiURqeCPSrjlY@ET9kHxyMyUoOJEZF4pcrpUUl8PDaCqnuS@i61taoa5m7x2JxPesIxH90RXTenHk6rFkyl@iE5Sm8whUCu8zpID7zNSy5laJWszbNGXjInUgvQQxsrwfFKIKOykPybu66s8xNLBCQyOXPRTd1SHrGA8BB1NVnqczdSTfixXq4vp2n58PNc/DgMU/Fr@HvY7E4Pq0X410yH9yn8bvg/s4mqx2XgrlZiuTt9YhhXwZ3l7R8) / [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fVW9bttADN46-Cm0FLFaBbg__blx505dO8gaJNdGAqR24CgF8ixdDBTtI_Rd2qepjvfxjvGQ4XDSkfxIfiTvfvx-eJ5uj4fzz_168-tp2l83fz_cD9_Gr0M2FONar7pxte7Gd0vzfrm9sSrP39amGD-qvtvemLLfH0_ZNrs7ZEPfXes-QPx782c_3D8-r7vOqr5YdKYsMquKzO8V7XTazl9YrvYa_tTqdGqaebl5WXFWzctr-zOF_yp8w9ssiSgVPDuBUAYEOvMeDKxd-LYmyKxlNNIs4c9Bs4Gm4XPSZkwdtCxbOkSMqMmyuohJiVhtwDA1oVZA0sGSFqNoIXPI3CJDb2ci18iPJAY-mVGHpUSmHEti1SaGwDVypVNII-cNsLkeBjvzX-O7IaQ6aDqD-E2USG5aZF1CQydssiqFH_wH3vt-sZhOT9NtaEtAYXfaO5ptEB43K--vLafITHPzxrJzSzVYKArpWMja1BqymOSXW1imU0GPaXCyRVibLciqFq3KJSxfRkHegE5eRWtbzqISI1fH4VDwolIrR1QbW6eEPZhxwkfEt8kHxcMyHj_4NTbFyyzHoeL4qG0YVdYk1p251YINkUNs6zYxRnUK-ciKSN74KuDm5-qzBy1y5NqgC4HMVSzFgPMYyQpoIWtSr1nHmVu-Mpl3HnyPRFeCVSILzr--qEqbRiwuIFm-fHXSjdUSHnEBYRAlmyTlK6sVnNCwPpzuDtPy6vMx-7QbpuzL8H232hyu8oV_c6bd4-SfHXpnVkF1v_Snec6Wm8MrhuEquLAMz9f5HPb_)

Unfortunately `reduce` was moved into the `functools` library in Python 3. So, this uses a list comprehension workaround to match the Python 2 version's length.

Clean `True`/`False` output is **61 bytes**: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVU7j9swDN7zK7wUl7QpIInyK0g6d@rawfHgpAnugKsT5NwC9@tTi/oosRluICTz8fEp@vo@PV9Gaq63@3m3v78Ovw@/hmJYH3Z20x02u@7weem@LI9bMqvVp9qtD99M3x23ruzPl1txLF7GYui7r7bf2vt5eH1733UdmX696Fy5Lsisi3BWfDK3nW8gXweNwCWbua6Zyc9EilfNFLQDz@C7ind4myUJpYJnrxDKiMC84MHB2sc7uSgjEjTWLOHPQ7OBphM@awumjVoklh4RI2q2rB5iMipWihiuZtQKSDZaMgmKVTKPzAkZBjuXao38WOLgUyrqQUZlKrHkqlKuEGqNXJkLaap5A2zph8Mp9a9xbxipjpreIX6XJLo2LbIuoWEzNluVyg@@Y937frGYbn@m5ziWgMLpbXA02yA8GVY5PyJv2MzK8Ka2mzwoTGgK6xBkbR4N3Uz2KyOs06mg1@YxzSMi2mLBVrUaVWlh@X8U7A3o7FWNNkkWlXpydXocBl5MHuWESml0StijMl75SPiUfXA8IiM1mBgRiVeqnB6VxMdjI6i6J6nvUlurqmEeFo/N@aQnHPPRHdF1c@rhNGrBlKofkqP0BlMI5Cqvg/TAm7zkUoZWyZo8a@QlcyK1AD20sRIcrwQyKgvJv37oSpufWCIgkcmZi27qlvKIBYSHqKvJUp@7kWrCj/V6exmn5dOPS/H9NEzFz@HvabMfn1aL8LeZTm9T@OHwf2YTVc/LwF2txHI/fmAYV8GD5f0f) / [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fVU7jttADO1S-BRqgrUTLzA__Qwrdaq0KWQVkmNjF9jIC682wJ4ljYEgOULukpwmGs7jDONii8FIQ_KRfCRnvv96fJnuTuPlx7HZ_XyejrfVn-ah_zp86bN-PTR60w6bph3eLc375X5r1Wr1tjTr4YPq2v3W5N3xdM722f2Y9V17q7utDiB_3_w-9g9PL03bWtWtF63J15lV68zvBe10Ws9fWK70Gv7U6nRqqnm5eVlxVszLa_szhf8ifMPbLIkoBTw7gZAHBDrzHgysXfi2JsisZTTSzOHPQbOCpuFz0mZMHbQsWzpEjKjJsriKSYlYbcAwJaEWQNLBkhajaCFzyNwiQ29nItfIjyQGPplRh6VEphxLYtUmhsA1cqVTSCPnFbC5HgY781_iuyKkMmg6g_hNlEhuamSdQ0MnbLLKhR_8B967brGYzs_TXWhLQGF32juabRAeNyvvry2nyExz88ayc0tVWCgK6VjI6tQaspjkl1tYplNAj2lwskVYmy3IqhStyiXM_4-CvAGdvIrWtpxFIUaujMOh4EWlVo6oNrZODnsw44SPiG-TD4qHZTx-8GtsipdZjkPF8VHbMKqsSaw7c6sFGyKH2NZ1YozqFPKRFZG88VXAzc_VZw9a5Mi1QRcCmauYiwHnMZIV0EJWpV6zjjO3fGUy7zz4HomuBKtEFpx_eVWVOo1YXECyfPnqpBurJTziAsIgSjZJyldWLTihYX0834_T8ubTKft46Kfsc__tsNmNN6uFf3Wmw9PkHx56ZzZB9bj0p6sVW-7GVwzDVXBlGZ6vyyXs_wA)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 54 bytes

```
b=1
for c in input():b=[b*(2+(c<30))%72,b>0][c<25]
1/b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVTNcpswEL77KTR0OoaauEISYDuhtx56y51yqClumamBATFp8gA99xn7Iq5@diU1h2YiA/vz7e63u5qe5fdxYLc37fi1H75Vq7xs@us0zpL0Y0qW5@WeXObxSpb1PM1j2y0LAf3jOHVDSh4/PX7c6Nc4kt0il/30HKXRU5Tsn@ZednEURbdzlW0u40xa0g/qf1plnJzOVX1@F7Nd3D5wmiRvS5aeP9Cmbh9Y3myy9@ebcq2z013WJPfkpaIGQmoIldZ@kSrh04aov/5CXk5kmvtBmu8XFQ7kslbuVbX9PGxPyrdSAg2I6mGURJ5IOw6yH9bOiCdlZWqLax2n@9m1q/xy/tGl27t1m26xym2j@NFJVJqC5N4679vxel2Hvv2iao/lTkdO9t2g@O3iBKwg/3GVQNIi53jaz51cZ2OZkB3Zkj@/fqvfHZHJrea02dQsTwmnKdHPwjy18Khe4IhSGyghz7yQHdQR6vBAVqijjbWMwndh320opXAgBYQVAUBuAYxMB2DgLOw7Z1bHOYAZwxyiCTA8gCFDuTZGxMwacXQUkC6kbByLVxnRIFNuMVipQQsAyqyjOQiSBToBZXMoT/sxZBlqMwoGEZFMAYcGZWImjlDuybEsQ51GCErH9gGQsRMMnsh8Ce8HDVRaQ8Egd4aKkJUjFJyDQeaRjVMeRIFvy3izUSOFCPAUao1qZQkp4Vzi839HUOOWwaC6LlM/FuZAE4wNB93RT0LYPBMW5zWsoQC7o59JNxFojA7GqQzmEnuW/5uECQbgJmgwxxyLKILtKnERKAShfm4dKMdJycEbaBFBBIfOfQSTDep4MIYwE5gtUuwWCLPTc4KgYT9cx5HXLKCCvrpgMl@N21ZTTdiMkDMWLMkhuEjyoBdYIfYFxs8CF37v3Sof/FXmyssC3cFPGRdQNufBNSfAGHaf6d3nNCgBay9fNeTo98kdAOLUl422rlFBQHvRwNKFRBql8I1wfPDmLw)

This full program [outputs via its exit-code](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5330/53748):

- `1` (the program raised a `ZeroDivisionError`) if the list contains a heat wave
- `0` (the program exited normally) if it does not

## [Python 3+](https://docs.python.org/3/), 60 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVTNbpwwEL7vU1grVUBDtsY2P7sJvfXQW@6Uw0KIipQFBKZp8gA99xn7IlvbzNhuDl3Jwjs/38w3P55e5fdx4Nf@Mo2zJP0Yk@V1uSNP83ghy9pM89h2y0JA/zBO3RCTh68PX3b6Gu5lt8jlML3u4/3LPjq8zL3swv1@f23KZPc0zqQl/UC6H@fnsB@mVYZRdGrKqvkYspuwvec0ij7kLG4@07pq71la75JPzVUBVMnpNqmjO/JWUgMkNZBK7rDIx3447Yj69U/k7USmuR8UsJG8qbCgkZUCKMvg2xCclHepBBoS1cMoiTyRdhxkP6ydEU/KynAMKx2p@9m1qzw3z10c3K5BHCDboFZ10mmUuhTR3eZ8aMfLZR369qxqEMobHTk6dEM7PnaKN1iZZKfD3Ml1NqqYBH9@/Q5iImPSDY9lEETXitN6V7E0JpzGRH8z89XCo7rAEbk2UEKeOCEr1BHqcE@WqaONtYzC/2y7b6GUwoJkEFZ4AOkGYGQ6AANnsd0523ScA5gxTCGaAMMCDBnKtTEiJpsRR0cB6ULKxjF7lxH1MuUbBss1aAZAyeZoDoIknk4AbQ70tB/DKgM3o2AQEYsp4FCPJmZiC8pdcbYqA08jBKWtdgHI2AkGX6x8DvdCA@WboWCQO0OFX5UjEE7BIHHIxin1osD/reL1To0UIsBXqNWplCWkhHOJ3/8dQY1bAoNqu0zdWJgDTTA2HHRHNwl@80xYnFefQwZ2RzeTdiLQGB2MU@7NJfYs/TcJEwzATVBvjjmSyLztynERKAShbm4tKMdJScEbyiK8CBaduwgmG9RxbwxhJjBbLLFdIMxOzwmC@v2wHce6Jl4p6LsHJnFs7LYaNn4z/Joxb0kK7yFJvV4gQ@wLjN8GnLm9t6tcuKfM0ks8XeGmjAugzbn3zAkwht1nevc59Sgg9/xdQ45un@wBIE4dbbS1jfICbg8NLJ1fSKMUrhG2Hrz@Cw) - Same as the Python 2 version above, but using `eval(input())` in place of `input()`.

## [Python 3.8+](https://docs.python.org/3/), 59 bytes

```
for c in eval(input())+[b:=1]:b=[b*(2+(c<30))%72,b/b][c<25]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVTLbpwwFN3PV1hIFdCQKdjmMaQsu@gue8oiQ4iKlAEEpmnyAV33G/sjUz/utd0sOpKF5z7Ovec@vLyK7/PEqmW9jpdlXgUZ54Rsr9sdeVrnC9n287LO/bBtBPT38zJMCbn/ev/loK5RIIZNbMflNUiClyA@vqyjGKIgCK5P80p6Mk5k@PHwHI3Tsosojm/ac91kXX1u2vPHiN5E/WeWxvGHkibnT@eu7T/TvLtK/zarb7MuviNvTXpQWEJhydyOm3gcp/pA5G98Im81WdZxktha8tZkqBGtBGia8NsU1tK7kQIFieppFkTUpJ8nMU77oMWLtNIUo1ZFGn4O/S4ezs9DEt7uYRIi2bCTZVJpNKoS8Z1xPvbz5bJPY/8gSxCJGxU5Pg5TPz8OkjpY6WSX4zqIfdWqhIR/fv0OEyISMkyPTRjG15al3aGleUJYmhD1LfRXCU/yAoeXykAKWeaEtJKHy8M8WSGPMlayFP4X5m5CSYUFKSAs9wByA6BlKgAFZ27ujBodYwCmDXOIxsGwAkOKcmWMiJkxYujIIV1IWTsW7zJKvUyZwaClAi0AKDOO@iBI5uk40GZAT/lRrDJw0woKEbGYHE7q0cRMbEGZK46pMvDUQlDaaleAjJ2g8MXKl3CvFFBpDDmF3Ckq/KqcgHAOBplD1k65FwX@m4p3BzlSiABfLlenlZaQEs4lfv93eKrdMhhU2@XUjYU@0ARtw0B3cpPgN0@HxXn1ORRgd3IzaScCjdFBO5XeXGLP8n@T0MEAXAf15pghicLbrhIXIYUgqZtbC8pwUnLwhrJwL4JFZy6CzgZ1zBtDmAnMFktsFwizU3OCoH4/bMexrplXivTdA5M5NnZbNRu/GX7NqLcklfeQ5F4vkCH2BcbPABdu7@0qV@4ps/QyT1e5KWMcaDPmPXMcjGH3qdp9lnoUkHv5riEnt0/2ABBLHW20tY3yApqHBpbOL6RWctcIWw/W/QU) / [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fVW9bpxAEE6aFPcG6VYnRUCML-wuf8eZMkU6pyYUBnMKkg8QLHHsB0idPo0b553sMk-S_ZmBjYtYWu3e_Hwz880M_vV7uBNf--7h6XN7GvpRkLb3yXQ3Hchx7E9kmqth7OtmmgjoL_uh6Xxy-eny40Y93a1oJjHthrutv73dervbsRWNu91uH2dxPE-fDsd-JDVpO9J8u7px226Yhet5Z0WV5bTMqryo3rvszK0veOB57xLmVx-qsqgvWFQaiOfXryRcQbNzWnoHcp8HG4UpFKZMdTeJ67bLNkT-tUdyn5FhbDsZQ0vuc4oaUUiAPHe-dE4mvXMpUJCo7npBREbqvhNtNzdaPEgrXbFbqEjN96aexVV10_jO-ez4DtbulJI1lUauiPEOxnlX96fT3LX1lWTEFWcqsrdrurq_biQFYKWTHXZjI-ZRq3zi_Pnx0_GJ8EnTXeeO4xkiHp7fvC14UG4KFvmEBz5Rd6xvJdzLB5wwUQZSyOkqZKk8oTzcksXyKGMlC-B3bN4mlFQsIDGEDS2AyABomQrAwDk0b86MjnMA04YRRAvBMAVDhnJljIjUGHF0DCFdSFk7xi8yCqxMucFgiQKNAYgaR30QhFq6EMrmUJ7yY8gy1KYVDCIimSGcwCoTM1kI5Ss5hmWoUwtBubCdAjJ2gsGNzCfwThVQYgxDBrkzVNis7KHgCAzoiqydIisK_DaMlxs5UogAdyh3qJCWkBLOJd7_O2Gg3SgM6tJlnJ8UDjRB23DQ7ddJsJunw-K82jXEYIe1h9ZEoDE6aKfEmkvsWfRvEjoYgOug1hxzLCK2tivBRQggSLDO7QLKcVIi8AZaQivCgs7XCDob1OGmQVTG12yR4mWBMDs1Jwhq92PpOPJKLSqsCpYp3q906R7pauxm2JzhzuOoY-MxALUqxL7A-BlgbGBkrTLujE0-tXTpOmU8hLI5fheRc1xxBaR2nwdWCVh78qIh-3WflgNAHD-wdLVdGmUFNB8aWDqbSK3EL9Pe4oPD_8q_)

Alternative 59 bytes:

```
b=1
for c in eval(input()):b=[b:=b*(2+(c<30))%72,b/b][c<25]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVTLbpwwFN3PV1gjVUBDpmCbx5Cy7KK77CmLQIiKlAEEpmnyAV33G/sjUz/utd0sOpKF5z7Ovec@vLyK7/PEymW9jpdlXgUZ55hsr9sdeVrnC9n2blnnftg2Avr7eRmmmNx/vf9yUNfwKIZNbKfl9RgfX47R6WUdxRAej8drV6eHp3klPRknMvx4eA7HadlFGEVVVzddVXcfQ3oT9p9ZEkUfChp3n7q26T/TrL1K/yatbtM2uiNvdaJxhMKRuZ028ThO1YHI3/hE3iqyrOMkcbXkTUYFjWgkQF0H36agkt61FChIVE@zIKIi/TyJcdoHLV6klaYYNirS8HPod/HQPQ9xcLsHcYBkg1aWSaVRq0pEd8b51M@Xyz6N/YMsQShuVOToNEz9/DhI2mClk11O6yD2VatiEvz59TuIiYjJMD3WQRBdG5a0h4ZmMWFJTNQ3118lPMsLHF4oAylkqRPSUh4uD/NkuTzKWMkS@J@buwklFRYkh7DcA8gMgJapABScubkzanSMAZg2zCAaB8MSDCnKlTEipsaIoSOHdCFl7Zi/yyjxMmUGgxYKNAeg1DjqgyCpp@NAmwE95UexysBNKyhExGJyOIlHEzOxBWWuOKbKwFMLQWmrXQIydoLCFytfwL1UQIUx5BRyp6jwq3IGwhkYpA5ZO2VeFPhvKt4e5EghAny5XJ1GWkJKOJf4/d/hiXZLYVBtlxM3FvpAE7QNA93ZTYLfPB0W59XnkIPd2c2knQg0RgftVHhziT3L/k1CBwNwHdSbY4Ykcm@7ClyEBIIkbm4tKMNJycAbysK9CBaduQg6G9QxbwxhJjBbLLFdIMxOzQmC@v2wHce6pl4pkncPTOrY2G3VbPxm@DWj3pKU3kOSeb1AhtgXGD8DnLu9t6tcuqfM0ks9XemmjHGgzZj3zHEwht2navdZ4lFA7sW7hpzdPtkDQCxxtNHWNsoLaB4aWDq/kFrJXSNsPVj7Fw) / [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fVW9bpxAEE6aFPcG6VZIERDjC-wuP8eZMkU6pyZXGMwpSD5AsMSxHyB1-jRunHeyyzxJ9mcGNi5iabV78_PNzDcz-Nfv4U587buHp8_taehHQdo-INPdtCfHsT-Raa6Gsa-baSKgv-yHpgvI5afLjxv19BzRTGLaDndO4Nw6_vZ2bEXjOY7zOIvjefa0r4poc-xHUpO2I823qxuv7YZZeL6fV0VZ5UX13qNnXn3BQt9_l9Kg-lAdyvqCxgcD8fz6lYQro_w8Ovh7cl-EGk8oPJnqdhLXbZdviPxrj-Q-J8PYdhJfS-5ldNCIUgIUhfulc3PpXUiBgkR11wsiclL3nWi7udHiQVrpir1SRWq-N_UsrqqbJnDPZzdwsXb3IFlTaRSKGH9vnLd1fzrNXVtfSUY8caYi-9umq_vrRpYPVjrZYTs2Yh61KiDunx8_3YCIgDTddeG6viHi4fnN25KFh01J44CwMCDqTvSthDv5gMNTZSCFLFqFNJOHy8MsWSKPMlayEH4n5m1CScUCkkBYbgHEBkDLVAAKzty8GTU6xgBMG8YQjYNhBoYU5coYESNjxNCRQ7qQsnZMXmQUWpkyg0FTBZoAUGQc9UGQyNJxKJtBecqPIstQm1ZQiIhkcjihVSZmshDKVnIMy1CnFoJyYTsDZOwEhRuZT-GdKaDUGHIKuVNU2KzsoOAYDKIVWTvFVhT4bRg_bORIIQLcXO5QKS0hJZxLvP93eKjdIhjUpcs4PxkcaIK2YaDbrZNgN0-HxXm1a0jADmvn1kSgMTpop9SaS-xZ_G8SOhiA66DWHDMsIrG2K8VFCCFIuM7tAspwUmLwBlq4FWFBZ2sEnQ3qcNMgKmVrtkjxskCYnZoTBLX7sXQceY0sKqwKlinerXTpHulq7GbYnOHO46hj4zFAZFWIfYHxM8DYwNhaZdwZm_zI0mXrlDEOZTP8LiLnuOIKSO0-C60SsPb0RUN26z4tB4AYfmCj1XZplBXQfGhg6WwitRK_TDuLDwb_K_8C)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pa`, 52 bytes

```perl
map{$_<25?$w=$h=0:$w++;$h+=$_>29;$\|=$w>4&&$h>2}@F}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83saBaJd7GyNRepdxWJcPWwEqlXFvbWiVD21Yl3s7I0lolpsZWpdzORE1NJcPOqNbBrbb6/38jMx0FI0sgNtVRMDYAYiMg2wKIzSDY2BhIA8WNDJHkLCBixiYg/C@/oCQzP6/4v25BIgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 35 bytes

```
1#.(1,2~:/\24<])(2<1#.29<]*4<#);.1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVQ9TwMxDN37KyI6XItKSezcVykTEhMTYqQToqpYkBAMLPz14/xsp0FCSk85x373/PzSt@li2xzD7S40YRNi2M2/q224e3y4n9Jyu0ob@tldP1PeH9Yr2s8hGveHy7xfrm@26TCtF2Hx@nJ6D8fA0Xc02sp9FeXkB0OgHIj9tQs0582vEftONhUYe2U3R1GpZa2UyesMR6jJsmGSIHNVL0kt4DOSBiSRRkqeIiXJYC3IYAViUtBVX47OhaWE@oLSoThJgSytTB7M6IXBfM6kWjGwlwPCF1SYjBWdv37zjzZsTVeKoQ2J4sx0G4CnYhKeKmCPzVCKe0nKBJZUH5SuR/TU4jgZnmS3Dow9pFtodfP08fV5@m4WZ68ABs@cPJoCWHE8P/9dOUpq5SsbWbTpyoLGcsQIjjbNMg2BV1sVzh1OR3PQn5lqnqZKdu8m0gG05y8JLrAE3Y3Gyqxzl/e1PyMQo5nLULiecmu2mld2VINkQ5XPapDdMRik0lFxzMlKocxVUYqINhmVJnlrsbq6yWjaDTnTLEKW/slNO/j1al1BZa1SwgkVUGe3zG7PYH8Lxjx5cLCJc656Yfb/iow8XDSiynhGUrvqKy1Hs7MtFHO0XjTB1HXo6gLD8EUVOcumojXJ0y8)

Returns `0` for `Falsy` and positive integer for `Truthy`

I feel it's too descriptive, so it's certainly golfable.

### Explanation:

I split `x u;.1 y`the input list of values into sublists that are smaller or greater/equal to 25. `x` is a binary mask denoting the intervals, y is the input list

`(1,2~:/\24<])` finds if each item is greater or equal to 25; then marks the boundaries of the intervals and prepends 1 to the list for the start.

```
    (1,2~:/\24<]) 1 1 25 30 25 30 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 40 1 1
1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0

    ((1,2~:/\24<])<;.1]) 1 1 25 30 25 30 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 40 1 1
┌───┬──────────────────────────────────────┬───┐
│1 1│25 30 25 30 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 40│1 1│
└───┴──────────────────────────────────────┴───┘
```

`(2<1#.29<]*4<#)` Checks if the length `#` of the sublist is at least 5 and sets all items to 0 if not by multiplying the list by the result of the check; then checks if there are 3 or more items that are greater or equal to 30.

```
   ((1,2~:/\24<])(2<1#.29<]*4<#);.1]) 1 1 25 30 25 30 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 40 1 1
0 1 0
```

`1#.` adds up the partial results

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 91 bytes

```java
h->{int e=0,a=0,t=0;for(int i:h)t=(e=i<25?0:e+1)>4&(a=i<25?0:i<30?a:a+1)>2?1:t;return t>0;}
```

Hopefully we'll have a heat wave here in The Netherlands soon, since it's currently 13 °C again (even though it was 24 °C this weekend..)

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##lVbBbtswDL33K3QaYixNZUmOnbhJbrutl@5W9KCm7uIudQpH6VAU@fZMpkmL66GIgAi2JZF8JB/JPNs3e/n8@Oe03tr9Xvy0dfNxIUTduKp9sutK3HSfQjzsdtvKNmI98kd398Impd8/@uV/e2ddvRY3ohELcdpcLj/8JVEt5Nj65RayfNq1naCo55vELUbVor5W2UrOq@9psjTfRpY26mstV3Zuu321SueubCt3aBvhlrI8nsre4OvhYesNot23Xf0oXjzy0a1r6@b33b1NetRXV@JXe3Cb9zl83r7vXfUy2R3c5NVfdNtm1EzWo6b6K8CrDy3HQs3Ggp4mPSbg6Bmy6Vj4n8pQmj2/WkaCWIQd7a9r0y8l8Vng0n7lfq@7o/HM@6EMfiv/TvKyf4dz1cuA/BTvzfDZ6cjPx9fJk07SC7rzHiPo1D0eiBLDCpgQA2Cj@6o/A3@mKCvRVx2BTSIWzC/4SLZBZ4SuDLFgLgzDO2DVAS/4Rmca44o@KB18p7wq9HHwtYjgCNrmXBm4TTlPWfxZPIBHaYgN@AnyEbHhfOL5VOiLRDvE3YzxhOJFnMF6jLJPHMQqBA4ViIPzJ2VnRagnbeJiDfpmjA8KsXf2VIQuyeJGeck/cQpzp/lCe3B/Gmp8yKHBHNI9Fcdzrf/nAugwgUtDrr6sxaTsDqgx/7DbfXV@Y44APAtkNnkccYbimDGCarY3paaDBEJCqViCalaIU0ycYXYyDCgViGLNXoXGHNX8iAgZYjdheFCT7fcjdJrQMIahlIWBMzQxhXHi/knmNxI@dtCAPSyAoUjYkBtwpWE49gMukk8Yd5BXiJ/4YFgzz1iDM5EDhYps8CVCtggNlnQMvKLGR5yj5kwcy/E9YsDQ0DI4zMFeETk8JRtKFFMVmpsi3dmnPygZcQvtHS@Op38)

**Explanation:**

```java
h->{              // Method with integer-array parameter and boolean return-type
  int e=0,        //  Amount of subsequent 25+ days, starting at 0
      a=0,        //  Amount of 30+ days in the current 'heat wave', starting at 0
      t=0;        //  Result-flag, starting at 0
  for(int i:h)    //  Loop over the input-array
    t=            //   Change the flag to:
      (e=i<25?    //    If the current temperature is below 25 °C
          0       //     Reset `e` to 0
         :        //    Else (temperature is 25+ °C):
          e+1)    //     Increase `e` by 1
       >4         //    Validate if `e` is at least 5 now
      &(a=i<25?   //    If the current temperature is below 25 °C
           0      //     Reset `a` to 0
          :i<30?  //    Else if the current temperature is [25,29] °C
           a      //     Leave `a` the same
          :       //    Else (temperature is 30+ °C):
           a+1)   //     Increase `a` by 1
       >2?        //    Validate if `a` is at least 3 now:
                  //    If there is a 'heat wave':
        1         //     Change the flag `t` to 1 
       :          //    Else:
        t;        //     Leave the flag `t` unchanged
  return t>0;}    //  Return whether the flag `t` is 1 now
```

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 64 bytes

```
00>l3(?^$:1+{:64*)?v~~~~
  ^<v?)4:+1$~$?)+fe<
)?v^>$:@2
;n<   0<
```

Keeps track of the current number of summer days and tropical days, resets when a regular day is encountered. For every summer day it checks if the requirements for a heat wave is met.

Answer (score 1):

## Powershell, <s>75</s> 73 bytes.

*-2 bytes thanks to Veskah.*

based on [Javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/163202/80745) by @[Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)

```
$a=$b=0;$args|?{if($_-ge25){++$a-ge5-band($b+=$_-ge30)-ge3}else{$a=$b=0}}
```

returns an array or $null. Save as `get-heatWave.ps1` and test with script https://regex101.com/r/lXdvIs/2

```
$t = @(
    @(30, 29, 30, 29, 41),
    @(1, 1, 25, 30, 25, 30, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 40, 1, 1),
    @(31, 34, 34, 20, 34, 28, 28, 23, 27, 31, 33, 34, 29, 24, 33, 32, 21, 34, 30, 21, 29, 22, 31, 23, 26, 32, 29, 32, 24, 27),
    @(26, 29, 22, 22, 31, 31, 27, 28, 32, 23, 33, 25, 31, 33, 34, 30, 23, 26, 21, 28, 32, 22, 30, 34, 26, 33, 20, 27, 33),
    @(20, 31, 20, 29, 29, 33, 34, 33, 20),
    @(25, 26, 34, 34, 41, 28, 32, 30, 34, 23, 26, 33, 30, 22, 30, 33, 24, 20, 27, 23, 30, 23, 34, 20, 23, 20, 33, 20, 28),
    @(34, 23, 31, 34, 34, 30, 29, 31, 29, 21, 25, 31, 30, 29, 29, 28, 21, 29, 33, 25, 24, 30),
    @(22, 31, 23, 23, 26, 21, 22, 20, 20, 28, 24, 28, 25, 31, 31, 26, 33, 31, 27, 29, 30, 30),
    @(26, 29, 25, 30, 32, 28, 26, 26, 33, 20, 21, 32, 28, 28, 20, 34, 34),
    @(34, 33, 29, 26, 34, 32, 27, 26, 22),
    @(30, 31, 23, 21, 30, 27, 32, 30, 34, 29, 21, 31, 31, 31, 32, 27, 30, 26, 21, 34, 29, 33, 24, 24, 32, 27, 32),
    @(25, 33, 33, 25, 24, 27, 34, 31, 29, 31, 27, 23)
)

$f = @(
    @(30),
    @(31, 29, 29, 28, 24, 23, 29, 29, 26, 27, 33, 20, 26, 26, 20, 30),
    @(29, 29, 29, 47, 30),
    @(23, 31, 29, 26, 30, 24, 29, 29, 25, 27, 24, 28, 22, 20, 34, 22, 32, 24, 33),
    @(23, 24, 25, 20, 24, 34, 28, 32, 22, 20, 24),
    @(24, 28, 21, 34, 34, 25, 24, 33, 23, 20, 32, 26, 29, 29, 25, 20, 30, 24, 23, 21, 27),
    @(26, 34, 21, 32, 32, 30, 32, 21, 34, 21, 34, 31, 23, 27, 26, 32),
    @(29, 24, 22, 27, 22, 25, 29, 26, 24, 24, 20, 25, 20, 20, 24, 20),
    @(23, 33, 22, 32, 30),
    @(28, 21, 22, 33, 22, 26, 30, 28, 26, 23, 31, 22, 31, 25, 27, 27, 25, 28),
    @(27, 23, 42, 23, 22, 28),
    @(25, 20, 30, 29, 32, 25, 22, 21, 31, 22, 23, 25, 22, 31, 23, 25, 33, 23)
)

"Should be $true"
$t | % {
    [bool](.\get-heatWave.ps1 @_)
}

"Should be $false"
$f | % {
    [bool](.\get-heatWave.ps1 @_)
}
```

Comment: [You have an extra set of parens around `$b+=($_-ge30)`](https://tio.run/##fY3NCsIwEITvfYo9rJLQFNK/g0gw7yFSEkxrIVhpBQ9pnj3GEsGTy87OwMewj@ll5uVmrA3YCxdQCdSCH1HNw7Ke3NgT7IrBVC11eY4qxrbQ6n4lqHOxoZrTz/XGLsalvvfBZ/gEAZJkEEeSmjOoDgy@3pSUJVQyiFu1Cf74PzV8q5U0o/HVunNnPU32QvbYg@yoD28 "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
.γ25@}ʒg5@}30@O3@à
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f79xmI1OHWmMDh1OT0oEMf2OHwwv@/4821FEAIiNTHQVjA1QaHzYxAGszjAUA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##fVQ7TgQxDO05xYh6QBk7mU/DboGQqDjAaguQEKKioOYSnIA7cAQ6Cq40TJz3ErMFEiGzie1nv2fn5fX@4flxlXRze7077y6uuvPdevnzKWn/9v3@tP3XsL/T/dfH2q8HDX0nS99xj8Px7DD03fYnCcdu/2/FYG45gG67xrIkYJ@xdFvTdpZtFHcbskT8lu2b/qF8270UH/MfYbdgzzGmDThf0JgO5jQVcDPWAmR1uSQMDMENlPZS7izREb4BRWgGDQABh5YVg5pxNkrwBi3RIdTo2hAsG94pSgSqaMuWFAuyqtnNWQcE9XpUxcnr4KhwFZhWQ6vGCjD/XI0Xw3MmQA8IQOGT04IVUhe0XwlMAdF0JsAMAE/@4O7m1mUaUbYZLo5zAVoOJNkouBJY@3QiCPhRvxDI7MfWq5WnCJ5oJ1Bf9S@RdhmbEJUPteyy19LkiBMYqrotjmJ1ZyNbE0yBOakUqxN/RCHRBUjIg9qJG2JpA1d6nxUnoMU27Ryecp6NY2ur@jykNvq1hwUp@4yCyxSS1ZG3QNCm6ufekQo4tPenvCFkGbXZhQCRZEY3fcn1d@RoU9iKng/nNhG8rGyzoakEp4nMT/jOM8yBj3i6LNDMFyW4gWbe0ppW6JROHtBExo@/).

**Explanation:**

```python
.γ   }              # Group the (implicit) input-list by sections of:
  25@               #  >= 25
      ʒ   }         # Then only leave groups of:
       g5@          #  At least 5 items
           30@      # Check for each remaining value if its >= 30 (1 if truthy; 0 if falsey)
              O     # And get the amount of truthy values per group by taking the sum
               3@   # Check if that amount is >= 3 for each
                 à  # And check if any are truthy by taking the maximum
                    # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), 100 char, 200 bytes

```
∇r←f w;c;C;k;i;x
r←i←c←C←0⋄k←≢w
→0×⍳k<i+←1⋄→3×⍳∼25>x←i⊃w⋄c←C←0⋄→2
c+←1⋄C+←x≥30⋄→2×⍳∼(c≥5)∧C≥3
r←1
∇
```

I find useful traslate program construct if() with "→LineNumber×⍳∼" test:

```
  f¨(,30)(29,29,29,47,30)(31,29,29,28,24,23,29,29,26,27,33,20,26,26,20,30)(23,31,29,26,30,24,29,29,25,27,24,28,22,20,34,22,32,24,33)(23,24,25,20,24,34,28,32,22,20,24)(24,28,21,34,34,25,24,33,23,20,32,26,29,29,25,20,30,24,23,21,27)(26,34,21,32,32,30,32,21,34,21,34,31,23,27,26,32)(29,24,22,27,22,25,29,26,24,24,20,25,20,20,24,20)(23,33,22,32,30)(28,21,22,33,22,26,30,28,26,23,31,22,31,25,27,27,25,28)(27,23,42,23,22,28)(25,20,30,29,32,25,22,21,31,22,23,25,22,31,23,25,33,23)
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
  f¨(30,29,30,29,41)(1,1,25,30,25,30,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,40,1,1)(31,34,34,20,34,28,28,23,27,31,33,34,29,24,33,32,21,34,30,21,29,22,31,23,26,32,29,32,24,27)(26,29,22,22,31,31,27,28,32,23,33,25,31,33,34,30,23,26,21,28,32,22,30,34,26,33,20,27,33)(20,31,20,29,29,33,34,33,20)(25,26,34,34,41,28,32,30,34,23,26,33,30,22,30,33,24,20,27,23,30,23,34,20,23,20,33,20,28)(34,23,31,34,34,30,29,31,29,21,25,31,30,29,29,28,21,29,33,25,24,30)(22,31,23,23,26,21,22,20,20,28,24,28,25,31,31,26,33,31,27,29,30,30)(26,29,25,30,32,28,26,26,33,20,21,32,28,28,20,34,34)(34,33,29,26,34,32,27,26,22)(30,31,23,21,30,27,32,30,34,29,21,31,31,31,32,27,30,26,21,34,29,33,24,24,32,27,32)(25,33,33,25,24,27,34,31,29,31,27,23)
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

If it is better I write less test space someone say that to me...

Comment: Why do you localise your variables? The program will certainly work without `;c;C;k;i;x`

Comment: They are local v

Comment: @Adám They are local variables, if they are defined out that function, and are not declared local in the function, I suppose they could change what not have to change (a variable out the function)

Comment: So what? This is code golf. Code quality is of no importance at all.

Comment: @Adám yes formally correct and without possible Undefined Behaviour is a prerequisite of one function they came first than codegolf

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 114 bytes

```cs
using System.Linq;s=>s.Select((a,b)=>s.Skip(b).TakeWhile(c=>c>24)).Any(a=>a.Count()>4&&a.Where(b=>b>29).Count()>2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU5NS8MwGL7nV@Q0EqhhpsVZZgMy8KQgTOhh7JDGrAvrEs2bKmPst9esjTs8vB/PB4@COwVq6MHYFq9PEPSRvRr7vURIdRIAv3vXenlEZwRBBqPwjzOf@E0aSyD46NpssfQt0KhAKeClt@rJ2LDZZrhxrhN4h6sBKgFsrTutAiEya@h4H8wXaSj7kAdd702niaqEEryglD3bE5GVkGzlehsIFcVsJlm9116TphKN4CW9cZwOy1uBlbPgOs1qb4ImO2L1Lx774HN@n@G8mMDnaT4m5BGL@Ltq8sSVEUW6edz//fNpH3k@eUb/Q9KVaV4zFvhCaax3QZfhDw)

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 81 bytes

Without LINQ.

```cs
a=>{int b=0;foreach(int i in a){b+=i<25?-b:i>29?11:1;if(b>34)return 1;}return 0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVTbbptAEH3nK0Y8gepUe8H4QoxVVfVTKlWNqz60fVjwOlmJLBWXRpXlb3eAnQWUulKL0MBez8ycOUNa3qR5IS91qfQD3P8uK/kUOWkmyhI@FflDIZ5ODsDPOslUCmUlqubzK1cH@CiU9vx2E2BX6/RW6erbj1nzjuEAm4vYxKdmAsmGRMfGhUgfvXauQGkQ/il5s1G3bL69SdYqZqstpWsaqaOXxDzwC1nVhQYanXFEovMlcpz3uS7zTL79WqhK3iktPXf/KOGYZ1n@3GYgCgm7d3f3HyAVpSzXrh9duXTwtHyGLmA4cQJnPyZbd1/U0l27O5GV8h/uAVvNegsWM@BkEg6nAwxbNhY0xkdrYWMtfLtGcB6a8dTYW/zeb9jioF/rc258dmttTAz9BWbMmdnjfCp3HMHnmFSA4EsEZ3Z9Ir4NnBpcbn0FSCSS2fkKXyVORoRwg8EW1@O4psjv@k9N7j9/@S9JmmjsN6AwWVp99mRguDOOsqKGEW7Ljwx1zNj7BFlYYfkp3g/x3GqQBFtMlQRBYDKUwwZmtD@NA6zimIueX5sTNZXvzpBX7UiHUHoFTW27cFAZt@pbDi3dtzgd7S2H2vFgog7IqGY2x4Xxwcmo9hQ5sMbwnP3t0OEstx0cjM6xv8TnOOfmubwA)